# (Re)Implementing Tetris

Tags: code-challenge, popularity-contest, tetris

In the spirit of [re-implementing classic video games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10713/4098), I would like to invite the community to create their best implementation of [Tetris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris).

[image]
*For reference, a screenshot of the official NES version of Tetris.*

### Required Features

- A reasonable scoring system must be in place, which rewards multi-line clears more than single-line clears. The current score must be visible at all times.
- The next piece that will appear must be indicated in some manner.
- The distribution of the seven tetrominoes should be fairly even (i.e. pseudo-randomly chosen).
- The user must have the ability to rotate the current piece in both directions, as well as accelerate its descent.
- When the game has ended, it should be clearly indicated that the game is over.
- The source code must be structured and easily understandable.

### Optional Features

- Advancing falling speed after a certain number of clears (i.e. increasing difficulty level), and advancing score per line clear, proportional to speed.
- Gravity. You may choose to implement the 'classic' gravity, in which blocks can remain floating over gaps, or you may choose to implement 'flood fill' gravity, in which blocks which have been separated from their original tetromino via line clears may fall into open gaps.
- High scores with name input.
- Animation after line clears, and/or after obtaining a new high score.

### Limitations

- Any libraries used ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/), etc.) should be freely available.
- Source code size must not exceed 4096 bytes, excluding whitespace and comments. Any external resources (data files, images, etc.) will be added to the code length, excluding any files which are generated, such as for high scores.
  *I realize that this is a rather arbitrary restriction; my primary goal is to discourage copy-pasting of existing implementations, and to encourage brevity and self-containment.*

### Winning Criteria

This challenge will be judged as a **popularity contest**, meaning that the submission with the most upvotes will be selected as the winner. When upvoting, I encourage users to upvote any and all submissions which they feel adequately meet the above stated requirements.

The winner will be chosen no sooner than 2 weeks after the first valid solution. Additionally, I will be granting a bounty to the winner, roughly proportional to the number of upvotes this question receives (`10 * #votes` rounded upwards to the nearest 50). Should there be a tie after the 2 week period has expired, the competition period will be extended by one week. Should there still be a tie, I reserve the right to place the final vote.

Please ask for any clarifications. May the best implementation win!

Comment: @moose I do mean source code. The question has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: Hey primo, can I paste and early version and (maybe) update that later?

Comment: @HenrikMühe I don't mind, but it won't start the timer unless it meets the required feature set.

Comment: I definitely will want to try this out. Probably will do it with SDL (though I haven't used it before, so it will make it even more fun!).

Comment: If only I could find my QBASIC implementation of Tetris, though! :)

Comment: Um... primo, did the bounty go to the right submission?

Comment: Not mine, but very impressive IMO. http://nerdparadise.com/tech/python/pygame/2kbtetris/

Comment: These guys here did a great job. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to work on mine often enough to get it in. Also, SDL+OpenGL is too expressive and complex to get it within the constraints here. But nonetheless, I'm still going through with making it. Just now with less attention paid to golfing. :) [It's on GitHub, by the way.](https://github.com/benrichards86/Tetris)

Comment: Couldn't you only rotate a piece one way in the classic tetris? I recall having to rotate multiple times quickly because of this.

Comment: I guess I'll have to add counterclockwise rotation to my tetris game written in chip-8...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Try: http://tetris.muehe.org

***Update*** There's a global high score. Enjoy beating it or - alternatively - hacking it :-)

[image: Screenshot: Tetris in action]

CoffeeScript and HTML version, should fulfill the requirements to the best of my knowledge (and I have never really played Tetris).

```
$ make stats
4095
```

Github https://github.com/henrik-muehe/tetris

### Features

- Exponential scoring
- Next piece indicator
- Fair randomness
- Rotation, move and drop down
- Game over indication
- **Highscore** with server backend that should not be *that* easily fakeable.

Comment: Great! But a small bug: when multiple rows are completed at the bottom of the pit, one of them not disappears.

Comment: @manatwork You mean when one of the rows to disappear is the one the most towards the bottom? I'll look into it, a screenshot would be awesome :)

Comment: That is a very nice implementation. One request: could you list which of the features are implemented? As more solutions are submitted, it will make comparison easier.

Comment: @primo Thanks. I'll add the list of features later. Would it be ok with you if a shortened-identifier version is <=4096 bytes of code and I'd still also show the original? I don't like mangling the code too much as it makes modification harder and I could apply shortened identifiers and such automatically :)

Comment: Feel free to show the orginal as well. And a screenshot would probably be nice too ;)

Comment: I think there is a minor glitch with the highscore: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AzvcG.png

Comment: Yeah, I might look into that some day :)

Comment: @manatwork I have an insanely hard time reproducing your bug. I've added debug info to the server, if you can reproduce it more easily I'd be happy if you could trigger the bug again...

Comment: Nope, I can not. I was able to reproduce only the previously reported error, when one row of a multi-row combination is not removed. Here are screenshots [before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QWuq0.png) and [after](http://i.stack.imgur.com/atMbH.png). As with the next piece, regardless how you play it, the remaining row will be removed and another 1000 points awarded, you could say that its the way you implemented the multi-row bonus, so not a bug, but a feature. ;-)

Comment: So we have narrowed it down to only occur on Firefox, do you also use Firefox, potentially on Linux?

Comment: The `make stats` call shows it takes around 4000 loc!? That's a lot.

Comment: @user2023370, it's bytes, though...

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score 19):

## Pascal

Developed in FreePascal 2.6.2, should compile with Turbo Pascal 6.0 too. Only the [Crt](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/) unit is used, no external resources.

```pascal
program tetris;

  uses
    Crt;

  const
    width = 10;                                  { playing field width }
    height = 20;                                 { playing field height }

  const
    piece: array [1..7, 1..3, 0..1] of ShortInt = ( { piece shapes : piece, element, coordinate }
      (( 1, 0), ( 1, 1), ( 0, 1)),               { O }
      ((-1, 0), ( 1, 0), ( 2, 0)),               { I }
      (( 0, 1), ( 1, 0), ( 2, 0)),               { L }
      (( 0, 1), (-1, 0), (-2, 0)),               { J }
      ((-1, 0), ( 1, 0), ( 0, 1)),               { T }
      (( 1, 0), ( 0, 1), (-1, 1)),               { S }
      ((-1, 0), ( 0, 1), ( 1, 1))                { Z }
    );
    color: array [1..7, 0..1] of Byte = (        { piece colors : foreground, background }
      (Yellow,       Brown),                     { O }
      (LightCyan,    Cyan),                      { I }
      (LightBlue,    Blue),                      { L }
      (White,        LightGray),                 { J }
      (LightMagenta, Magenta),                   { T }
      (LightGreen,   Green),                     { S }
      (LightRed,     Red)                        { Z }
    );

  var
    area: array [1..width + 2, 1..height + 1] of Byte; { playing field }
    coord: array [0..3, 0..1] of Byte;           { precalculated element coordinates }
    played,                                      { played pieces count }
    removed,                                     { completed lines count }
    level,                                       { current level }
    score: LongInt;                              { accumulated score }
    time,                                        { current level delay }
    wait,                                        { current piece delay }
    made,                                        { completed lines in current level }
    multi,                                       { multiline count }
    screen,                                      { original screen size }
    i, j, j2: Word;                              { counters }
    current,                                     { current piece }
    next,                                        { next piece }
    x,                                           { horizontal coordinate }
    y,                                           { vertical coordinate }
    position,                                    { rotation position }
    k: Byte;                                     { pressed key }
    ok: Boolean;                                 { aggregated condition }

{ precalculates the give piece's elements coordinates }
  procedure coordinate(current, x, y, position: Byte);
  begin
    coord[0, 0] := x;
    coord[0, 1] := y;
    for i := 1 to 3 do begin
      coord[i, 0] := x + piece[current, i, position mod 2] * (Ord(position in [0, 1]) * 2 - 1);
      coord[i, 1] := y + piece[current, i, 1 - position mod 2] * (Ord(position in [0, 3]) * 2 - 1);
    end;
  end;

{ draws a piece }
  procedure draw(current, x, y, position: Byte; visible: Boolean);
  begin
    coordinate(current, x, y, position);

    for i := 0 to 3 do begin
      GotoXY(coord[i, 0] * 2 + 1, coord[i, 1]);
      if visible then begin
        TextColor(color[current, 0]);
        TextBackground(color[current, 1]);
        Write('[]');
      end else begin
        TextBackground(Black);
        Write('  ');
      end;
    end;
  end;

{ check whether a piece can be placed in given position }
  function check(x2, y2, position2: Byte): Boolean;
  begin
    coordinate(current, x2, y2, position2);

    ok := True;
    for i := 0 to 3 do if area[coord[i, 0], coord[i, 1]] <> 0 then ok := False;

    if ok then begin
      x := x2;
      y := y2;
      position := position2;
    end;

    check := ok;
  end;

begin

  Randomize;
  TextColor(LightGray);
  TextBackground(Black);
  ClrScr;
  screen := WindMax;

  for i := 0 to width + 1 do for j := 1 to height + 1 do area[i, j] := 9 * Ord(not ((i in [1..width]) and (j in [1..height])));

  Window(1, 1, width * 2 + 4, height + 2);
  for i := 1 to (width + 2) * (height + 1) do Write('##');
  Window(3, 1, width * 2 + 2, height);
  ClrScr;
  Window(1, 1, Lo(screen), Hi(screen));

  Window(width * 2 + 7, 1, width * 2 + 25, 10);
  Writeln('Next');
  Writeln;
  Writeln;
  Writeln('Piece');
  Writeln('Line');
  Writeln('Level');
  Writeln('Score');
  Window(1, 1, Lo(screen), Hi(screen));

  played := 0;
  removed := 0;
  level := 1;
  score := 0;

  current := 9;
  next := 9;
  made := 0;

  repeat

    if current = 9 then begin
      if next = 9 then next := Random(7) + 1 else draw(next, width + 9, 1, 0, False);

      current := next;
      next := Random(7) + 1;
      x := width div 2;
      y := 1;
      position := 0;
      time := 1100 - level * 100;
      wait := time;

      Inc(played);
      Inc(score);
      if made = 25 then begin
        Inc(level);
        made := 0;
      end;

      draw(next, width + 9, 1, 0, True);

      Window(width * 2 + 15, 4, width * 2 + 25, 10);
      TextColor(LightGray);
      TextBackground(Black);
      Writeln(played:5);
      Writeln(removed:5);
      Writeln(level:5);
      Writeln(score:5);
      Window(1, 1, Lo(screen), Hi(screen));

      if not check(x, y, position) then begin
        GotoXY(width * 2 + 7, 10);
        Write('Game Over');
        Break;
      end;
    end;

    draw(current, x, y, position, True);
    GotoXY(1, 1);
    repeat Delay(1);
      Dec(wait);
    until KeyPressed or (wait = 0);
    draw(current, x, y, position, False);

    if KeyPressed then begin
      k := Ord(ReadKey);
      case k of
        75, 77: check(x + Ord(k = 77) * 2 - 1, y, position);
        72, 80: check(x, y, (position + Ord(k = 80) * 2 + 1) mod 4);
        32: begin
          time := 1;
          Inc(score);
        end;
      end;
    end;

    if wait = 0 then begin
      if not check(x, y + 1, position) then begin
        draw(current, x, y, position, True);
        for i := 0 to 3 do area[coord[i, 0], coord[i, 1]] := current;

        multi := 0;
        for j := 1 to height do begin
          ok := True;
          for i := 1 to width do if area[i, j] = 0 then ok := False;

          if ok then begin
            for j2 := j downto 2 do for i := 1 to width do area[i, j2] := area[i, j2 - 1];
            for i := 1 to width do area[i, 1] := 0;

            Inc(score, 10 + multi * 2);
            Inc(removed);
            Inc(multi);

            Window(3, 1, width * 2 + 2, height);
            TextBackground(Black);
            GotoXY(1, j);
            DelLine;
            GotoXY(1, 1);
            InsLine;
            Window(1, 1, Lo(screen), Hi(screen));
          end;

        end;
        if multi <> 0 then Inc(made);

        current := 9;
      end;
      wait := time;
    end;

  until k = 27;

  ReadKey;
  TextColor(LightGray);
  TextBackground(Black);
  ClrScr;

end.
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Tetris in Pascal]

(On Linux, in XTerm window.)

#### Control

- <kbd>Left</kbd> – move left
- <kbd>Right</kbd> – move right
- <kbd>Up</kbd> – rotate counterclockwise
- <kbd>Down</kbd> – rotate clockwise
- <kbd>Space</kbd> – drop down
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> – exit

#### Scoring

- played piece – 1 point
- dropped piece – 1 point
- completed line – 10 point
- multiple lines – multiplier * 2 point

Level starts at 1 and increases after each 25 line completing. (Multiple lines completed at once count as 1.)

#### Measurement

```
bash-4.2$ sed '
s/{[^{}]*}//g                  # remove comments
s/^ *\| *$//g                  # trim leading and trailing spaces
/^$/d                          # remove empty lines
s/ *\([:=<>,;+*-]\+\) */\1/g   # no space around operators
' tetris.pas | wc -c
3697
```

Answer (score 18):

### Java (Swing)

This is an implementation of the first historical [Game Boy edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris_%28Game_Boy%29) from **Nintendo(c)** from 1989.

[image: Game Boy Tetris Nintendo]

How to play:

<kbd>Z</kbd> = rotate left
<kbd>X</kbd> = rotate right
<kbd>Left</kbd> = move left
<kbd>Right</kbd> = move right
<kbd>Down</kbd> = move down (slowly)
<kbd>Up</kbd> = rotate left (just for easier use)
<kbd>R</kbd> = reset game

I avoided to use more than one class (because the golf aspect comes to my mind). But now it's not golfable anymore in any case... However, I zipped and Base64-encoded one Font-File and one Image-File, so I can use it in the one and only class file.

To run it, copy the Java code into your IDE and start. You don't need any additional libraries or resources.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class JTetris extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static Image IMAGE;
    static Font FONT;

    static {
        ZipInputStream zipImage = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(
            "UEsDBBQAAAAIABmiWkRZ0oOouwAAAJYKAAAFAAAAYy5ibXBz8p3GxQAGZUCsAcQ3gFgCiBkZWMDiCkB5GBCA0iJyLAwl+3oYYpJsGK58u8NAKjBGAgyUgVG7QHYxKUGBAjDiBJUUQUhQAMQGA3xsFL3MMBMNRrpdEABhQxQLCiDYmHZBxCF2QdhAu8CyEHLk2cWkBJSH" +
            "xxcoCgyg5hsbAgWhbBgJUg9Wg24XWDGQHJF2QeOCUruQwEi0S0kRe5qHKCY2zQsgkv0ItAsIKC97EQnecGTYRQUwKNsbNAYAUEsBAj8AFAAAAAgAGaJaRFnSg6i7AAAAlgoAAAUAJAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAGMuYm1wCgAgAAAAAAABABgAkJCiSyczzwGQkKJLJzPP" +
            "AZCQoksnM88BUEsFBgAAAAABAAEAVwAAAN4AAAAAAA=="
        )));

        ZipInputStream zipFont = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(
            "UEsDBBQAAAAIAEq5UEN0MGyWoggAAHgrAAAFAAAAYS50dGbklsvvC1EUx78zU+/3OxHiEuLd1jMlxKNR70cQCxumY9oOnU5Np6osdIGEDYmwZGElkYh/gI2FBUIsvFdILNgh8Rxft4d6RyxEYvq7PZ97es73nHNv8mthAOiJFiyotRtS0xMnum4Gej0HsNXx7erbI6+7" +
            "ks8CxqNiuVk48qTbVKB3BIy8XXLtbVv6x0cBkwuzS3SYrffvuL8MYGzJj3av3BfP4P4p8yeUA8cGxqWBSau4n+Lbu6tYET8AEoMBqIrtuzuPz33D/Uyg28VqUItgxtTrvRGAAoW4LK7BsHTnb5HAE9qB6E+PidGYhCTmYjP24AxuxTGYR98UpLEIdtsXP4zvxXfjO/HN" +
            "+Gp8Kg6p9O8//8ucRns93ZK6vqXfvBccXLuv7b/QH2LjVtyyYLUAdIfJaMmz6Gc83w3yd9OuSLS0WmcxRLj1xYJY/Gz9Wcyfr79XJ6aO3MEKTEAPWsDE988Y4yQM4RGAsEEeIWyiGzLCFsZjgXACY1EQ7oJeOCzclZnHhbthHs4Ld8cQPBPugT6GKdwT841+wr0wzFgl" +
            "3BtpwxHugxHGMeG+mGycEx6EicbdNhusYFqwYCQ4LTJmL2GDnBU20dfcK2xhjXlIOIFl5i3hLhhqjRLuiow1S7gbdlu+cHdMsh4L98DwRD/hntiTmCjcC8nEaeHe2Jq4IdwHmS7ThPtiUxdPeBDWd7nYZgPo33VANqg2Q69YitQ6Owo9Z4daZdd3uGp6etqMDfWqG6rV" +
            "dugF9Fa2qQlL+T9XLQ6aE9V6t1gv22EuqEQborDuROoX0b/87JPUJjeseUFFTUumdfhUHT71Y/hUHT71Y/jULyp6NWWrKLS3ub4d7lBBQeU2LFc6oBRU1fJK5IYVO6KoXVZL/fyyUhRV56ZSBUbUtETSCfyv5h5+6fWveh1+6ZVq2DWVr3vlSDW8qKQ6/fQU+UajkdQl" +
            "2MTHAj+s+sWW/dVSDG6kMpnMjGlzsqHLpne5Khv4Pj9TiyJ2mK9/DBQtR0KcdkQyCIupsue4lZpbS+WbqRnJdCr3USLvFdXOuu3s8CpFtcetlpphTW0P2Lzf5CS7Vd7dli0uWbStXIqQRYAqmgjhoYgSIiisg41Iexzs4H4V93WSS56ONKZhBjbQU6UnpG81bB0dSGwF" +
            "20gTsJTs66zFCFhjImk990XmlnVODgGjI6qxHr0Orfoz7T/P+66rTVqjprMrUJw3ifQX6lM76mRRJ31WJ4s66cczetRXjFbaazPfha9VeeLMKPA9x5zltB2FEqlKz3K9Zy+0NomdaCpDsQcfeSzTdxkxei5SfBVEo9bpglM59Po/v281HJfw+k/PVWe/oqcBW0+bp47H" +
            "HiPt82hLpB+dT89vum/oV7IzhZyETPD7s/7wUzk/elKi3CBl9GsGb38Osox05aR36SmzWs2XPIVFiOQMOSVE8Zu+nG9UnK80krQhiowr65twtdfVXeXR5PsMxqRpc5+7yJOKtDtZ09a356GiPXvgsm6JeaHubzsCOXkfTbmT3VrB5Q1mmbMEi0hl3TNM86VxFF2QMOXL" +
            "XVsuNnEF8mtAHquDQG7DxvVYSOFbbbfVQovG0NwOVV/kFKj3g4eVJZ5/3dALAzGUIl8/MMTDAvEBAC9oe9Hu/WJ/kD9s78f3gfdvpKrPs6H/A+1VkJtADAMnWXFAqEIVqjhw6KEfzQvan/Ud/cQmJdnRjoyzBLUCFAxeZ8aOHSfgk3aU+Kp6oFqX7/mn2s5L6KF+JPoC" +
            "8QOVOqdFAqiOpICIqxbYo82LiTEcccIZF7zjgyiD14JJ9MrUfmsUWAlrx3nybJXJ/b6v1/yIene+vjHV+OQrxNUsQ5XCpSYvtZBCXZeWD85FbA8CGE3TXXlkQwTIJkI1cvQrGmlXFAOiWYslTyXZJ1XX5JWTeT8IXbEKNaBKky2OmVbG17et7AMet8D6Vlh1kZq8sgdj" +
            "RckB7b9Tnx3ELVCmouKUtBHriQZczDu8dlk1i5w+SwGrFYp5mvtc03aE9NdGqP2rSNu3slZt6Ea4zTmuQc/Zcu1q0XEqj52KR/J9YIIwfN4gZOREc/Xdi+O4W6/anb3a9dGGxBoe1NRf8szqSdveBHqRE8SK4PtAbHr2cXFqh9rORFwMcgVACL6qgdi+WY9mzbjJ1agC" +
            "A2Uh8jgnE1wOHu0lvY4L+RGIZCzMHsnS+bwfbljlmyIz/X2Cyaf8t0jUNzue7CR+ZC32wD0kgyL537VkJY/XUtXl4/f3DWJDnotxhmJ67IyMMD2if9qO9ovOCYvrzqWCIf5Z+I4H4iCiODiKdFob37e6M40fO8Cyqtp4cxjXh5iNz2KXn84f5pI65vQ5nKrUWbPJ+fy7" +
            "nMF/ARx6tzdmc0q43dv7n3IcnZlxcHefezcFAJt3de7FX/bLHQWAEAaiuPe/srhiMcEncWDZMkUKwe/oJM+R+Ip1IqfPB1WCakTEbi7q6Jyb9sZ5oAgoYThNGjp24i9uhItx5j6DbyffdZC4XuWaY4gwHjnb1m/m0cxzUENOUK/VVs+f/S1qh79xC6dP/B+YfgEZgCsT" +
            "XRT0T4OPuu6oXXK5r1OxdrBO2xkcikrZz/l3jjozreH9LYpVi1WLVYtVi1VfjbZVGUfbqqNt1dG26mhbFaBB21blBJIgO+HzavBZNXWgKUQCsK8w58oQKQJ19BhR5mHMyUHYuOfWEHOEmL7+B49bDP3Dc/4Q0DW9aSsURmEYfqGx97+Po31eu4MFYdglBEHw47qIMAiD" +
            "YEEQBAuCYF1AGIZBGIRBGARB0MvBA3N8MMccc3wAkN1Zu2umvfeihkba+ueezEstLSxnogE8JMpk9thQDqGsVIWO8JSq0Bmeo/bwEjTUCV57Mn/ragPvUZkO1iWV+8u5rvDRl/NnRyv4CoqawndQ1Bx+0FhL+G0q1xX+oi6QDOAftTWBStAQqh0VUKtBvaTdDVBLAQI/" +
            "ABQAAAAIAEq5UEN0MGyWoggAAHgrAAAFACQAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAABhLnR0ZgoAIAAAAAAAAQAYAABukYC8ys4BJXTvDjUzzwEldO8ONTPPAVBLBQYAAAAAAQABAFcAAADFCAAAAAA=")
        ));

        try {
            zipImage.getNextEntry();
            zipFont.getNextEntry();
            IMAGE = ImageIO.read(zipImage);
            FONT = Font.createFont(0, zipFont);
            FONT = FONT.deriveFont(20.0f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    int[] speeds = {887,820,753,686,619,552,468,368,284,184,167,150,133,117,100,100,83,83,66,66,50};
    int[] points = {40,100,300,1200};
    int[][][] stones = {
        {{0,1},{1,1},{2,1},{0,2}},      // L 0
        {{0,1},{1,1},{2,1},{3,1}},      // I 1
        {{0,1},{1,1},{2,1},{2,2}},      // J 2
        {{0,1},{1,1},{2,1},{1,2}},      // T 3
        {{0,1},{1,1},{1,2},{2,2}},      // Z 4
        {{1,1},{2,1},{0,2},{1,2}},      // S 5
        {{1,1},{2,1},{1,2},{2,2}}       // O 6
    };
    Color[] colors = {
        new Color(220, 246, 212), // light
        new Color(140, 190, 116), // green
        new Color(60, 98, 92),    // blue
        new Color(4, 30, 20)      // dark
    };
    int FREE = 0;
    int BORDER = 8;
    int DELTA = 20;
    int WIDTH = 10;
    int HEIGHT = 20;
    int SIZE = 24;

    int[][] field = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    int[][] stone;
    int deltaX;
    int deltaY;
    int curStone;
    int nextStone = new Random().nextInt(7);
    int score;
    int level;
    int lines;
    int steps;
    int speed = speeds[0];

    Timer tickTimer = new Timer();
    Image dbImage;
    Image staticImage;
    Graphics dbg;

    int anim = -1;
    boolean blink = false;
    ArrayList<Integer> removeLinesRows = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean keyDown = true;
    boolean freezeKeys = false;

    private JTetris() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(2);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(475, 480);

        addPropertyChangeListener("isDirty", new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        });

        reset();

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosed(e);
                tickTimer.cancel();
            }
        });

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                keyDown = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (freezeKeys) {
                    keyDown = false;
                    return;
                }

                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                    case 82: reset(); break;
                    case 37: updateField(-1, 0, false); break;
                    case 39: updateField(1, 0, false); break;
                    case 40: if (keyDown) updateField(0, 1, true); break;
                    case 38:
                    case 90: rotate(false); break;
                    case 88: rotate(true);
                }
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void startTickTimer() {
        if (tickTimer != null) {
            tickTimer.cancel();
        }

        freezeKeys = false;

        tickTimer = new Timer();
        tickTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                updateField(0, 1, false);
            }
        }, 0, speed);
    }

    private void startRemoveLineTimer() {
        if (!removeLinesRows.isEmpty()) {
            anim = 7;
        }

        if (tickTimer != null) {
            tickTimer.cancel();
        }

        tickTimer = new Timer();
        tickTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (anim > 0) {
                    blink = !blink;
                    firePropertyChange("isDirty", false, true);
                }

                if (anim-- < 0) {
                    blink = false;
                    tickTimer.cancel();
                    if (removeLinesRows.size() > 0) {
                        int delta = 0;
                        for (int row : removeLinesRows) {
                            for (int r = row + delta++; r > 2; r--) {
                                for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) {
                                    field[c][r] = field[c][r - 1];
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        score += points[removeLinesRows.size() - 1] * (level + 1);
                        lines += removeLinesRows.size();
                        level = lines / 10;
                        speed = speeds[level > 20 ? 20 : level];
                        removeLinesRows.clear();
                    }

                    createNextStone();

                    startTickTimer();
                }
            }
        }, 50, 160);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        new JTetris();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (dbImage == null) {
            dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
            dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
            dbg.setFont(FONT);

            staticImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
            Graphics sg = staticImage.getGraphics();
            sg.setFont(FONT);

            sg.setColor(colors[3]);
            sg.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            sg.setColor(colors[0]);
            sg.fillRect(40 + WIDTH * SIZE + SIZE, 70, 170, 58);
            sg.setColor(colors[2]);
            sg.fillRect(40 + WIDTH * SIZE + SIZE, 73, 170, 52);
            sg.setColor(colors[0]);
            sg.fillRect(40 + WIDTH * SIZE + SIZE, 95, 170, 27);
            sg.setColor(colors[2]);
            sg.fillRect(40 + WIDTH * SIZE + SIZE, 98, 170, 3);

            sg.setColor(colors[1]);
            sg.fillRoundRect(40 + 13 * SIZE - 15, 40 + 13 * SIZE - 15, SIZE * 4 + 30, SIZE * 4 + 30, 20, 20);
            sg.setColor(colors[0]);
            sg.fillRoundRect(40 + 13 * SIZE - 12, 40 + 13 * SIZE - 12, SIZE * 4 + 24, SIZE * 4 + 24, 15, 15);

            sg.fillRoundRect(330 - 6, 60 - 6, 120 + 12, 25 + 12, 15, 15);
            sg.fillRoundRect(330 - 6, 155 - 6, 120 + 12, 60 + 12, 15, 15);
            sg.fillRoundRect(330 - 6, 235 - 6, 120 + 12, 60 + 12, 15, 15);
            sg.setColor(colors[2]);
            sg.fillRoundRect(40 + 13 * SIZE - 9, 40 + 13 * SIZE - 9, SIZE * 4 + 18, SIZE * 4 + 18, 15, 15);

            sg.fillRoundRect(330 - 3, 60 - 3, 120 + 6, 25 + 6, 15, 15);
            sg.fillRoundRect(330 - 3, 155 - 3, 120 + 6, 60 + 6, 15, 15);
            sg.fillRoundRect(330 - 3, 235 - 3, 120 + 6, 60 + 6, 15, 15);
            sg.setColor(colors[3]);
            sg.fillRoundRect(40 + 13 * SIZE - 6, 40 + 13 * SIZE - 6, SIZE * 4 + 12, SIZE * 4 + 12, 15, 15);

            sg.setColor(colors[0]);
            sg.fillRoundRect(330, 60, 120, 25, 5, 5);
            sg.fillRect(40 + WIDTH * SIZE + SIZE, 40, 3, (HEIGHT - 2) * SIZE);
            sg.fillRoundRect(40 + 13 * SIZE - 3, 40 + 13 * SIZE - 3, SIZE * 4 + 6, SIZE * 4 + 6, 5, 5);
            sg.fillRoundRect(330, 155, 120, 60, 15, 15);
            sg.fillRoundRect(330, 235, 120, 60, 15, 15);

            sg.setColor(colors[3]);
            sg.drawString("SCORE", 340, 80);
            sg.drawString("LEVEL", 340, 180);
            sg.drawString("LINES", 340, 260);

            for (int r = 0; r < (HEIGHT - 2) * 24 / 18; r++) {
                sg.drawImage(IMAGE, 16, 40 + r * 18, 16 + SIZE, 58 + r * 18, 8 * SIZE, 0, 9 * SIZE, 18, this);
                sg.drawImage(IMAGE, 40 + WIDTH * SIZE, 40 + r * 18, 40 + WIDTH * SIZE + SIZE, 58 + r * 18, 8 * SIZE, 0, 9 * SIZE, 18, this);
            }
        }

        dbg.drawImage(staticImage, 0, 0, this);

        dbg.setColor(colors[3]);
        dbg.drawString(String.format("%6s", score > 999999 ? 999999 : score), 320, 120);
        dbg.drawString(String.format("%4s", level > 20 ? 20 : level), 340, 205);
        dbg.drawString(String.format("%4s", lines > 9999 ? 9999 : lines), 340, 285);

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            drawField(dbg, stones[nextStone][x][0] + 13, stones[nextStone][x][1] + 13, nextStone + 1);
        }

        for (int r = 2; r < HEIGHT; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) {
                drawField(dbg, c, r - 2, field[c][r]);
            }
        }

        if (blink) {
            if (anim == 0)  {
                dbg.setColor(colors[0]);
            } else {
                dbg.setColor(colors[1]);
            }

            for (int row : removeLinesRows) {
                dbg.fillRect(40, 40 + (row - 2) * SIZE, SIZE * WIDTH, SIZE);
            }
        }

        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    private void drawField(Graphics g, int x, int y, int idx) {
        if (idx > DELTA) {
            idx -= DELTA;
        }

        g.drawImage(IMAGE, 40 + x * SIZE, 40 + y * SIZE, SIZE + 40 + x * SIZE, SIZE + 40 + y * SIZE, idx * SIZE, 0, (idx + 1) * SIZE, SIZE, this);
    }

    private void createNextStone() {
        curStone = nextStone;
        stone = stones[curStone];
        deltaX = (WIDTH + 1) / 2 - 2;
        deltaY = 1;

        if (!isMoveable(0, 0)) {
            tickTimer.cancel();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game over! Press OK for a new game.");
            reset();
            return;
        }

        updateField(0, 0, false);
        nextStone = new Random().nextInt(7);
    }

    private void reset() {
        score = 0;
        steps = 0;
        lines = 0;
        level = 0;
        speed = speeds[0];

        for (int r = 0; r < HEIGHT; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) {
                field[c][r] = FREE;
            }
        }

        createNextStone();
        startTickTimer();
    }

    private void updateField(int hor, int ver, boolean player) {
        if (isMoveable(hor, ver)) {
            if (player) {
                steps++;
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                field[stone[x][0] + deltaX][stone[x][1] + deltaY] = FREE;
            }

            deltaX += hor;
            deltaY += ver;

            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                field[stone[x][0] + deltaX][stone[x][1] + deltaY] = curStone + 1;
            }

            firePropertyChange("isDirty", false, true);
        } else if (ver == 1) {
            freezeKeys = true;
            fixStone();
            removeLines();
        }
    }

    private void removeLines() {
        outer:
        for (int r = HEIGHT - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
            for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) {
                if (field[c][r] == FREE) {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }

            removeLinesRows.add(r);
        }

        startRemoveLineTimer();
    }

    private void fixStone() {
        score += steps;
        steps = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            field[stone[x][0] + deltaX][stone[x][1] + deltaY] = curStone + 1 + DELTA;
        }
    }

    private boolean isMoveable(int hor, int ver) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            int c = stone[x][0] + deltaX + hor;
            int r = stone[x][1] + deltaY + ver;

            if (c < 0 || c >= WIDTH || r < 0 || r >= HEIGHT) {
                return false;
            }

            if (field[c][r] > DELTA) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void rotate(boolean r) {
        if (curStone == 6) { // O
            return;
        }

        synchronized (field) {
            int[][] o = new int[4][2];

            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                o[x] = new int[] { r ? 3 - stone[x][1] : stone[x][1], r ? stone[x][0] : 3 - stone[x][0] };
            }

            if (canRotate(o)) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    field[stone[x][0] + deltaX][stone[x][1] + deltaY] = FREE;
                }

                stone = o;

                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    field[stone[x][0] + deltaX][stone[x][1] + deltaY] = curStone + 1;
                }

                firePropertyChange("isDirty", false, true);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean canRotate(int[][] o) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            if (o[x][0] + deltaX < 0 ||
                o[x][0] + deltaX >= WIDTH ||
                o[x][1] + deltaY >= HEIGHT ||
                field[o[x][0] + deltaX][o[x][1] + deltaY] > DELTA) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**TODOs:**

- *faster stones on higher level* **(done!)**
- *original remove line animation* **(done!)**
- *correct points for lines* **(done!)**
- *interrupt moving down on new stone* **(done!)**
- highscore screen
- original rotation behavior
- menu for choosing level
- game-over screen
- audio

Comments are welcome :)

Comment: I really, really like this one. One suggestion for usability: when the user holds ↓ to drop a block, programatically 'release' this key after the block lands (that is, the user would need to release the key, and then press it again to make the next block accelerate).

Comment: Great! I was already thinking about, how to handle it. This will be a good method! Thanks!

Comment: +1 For making me squeal like a eight year old with his first Nintendo GameBoy!

Comment: Not sure if horrible Java code is horrible or retro. +1 anyways. ;)

Comment: For any class which is used once and only once, you are guaranteed to shorten your code by not importing it, and instead using the fully qualified name in the code.  For example, remove `import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;` and change `new KeyAdapter` to `new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. At least it's a popularity contest, so there is no need to golf this code. As you can see, all variables aren't shortened either.

Comment: Note that this program is 9.95 KiB when golfed.

Answer (score 10):

## Lua - 2876

Tetris in a terminal, works on most unix systems, pure lua, no additional libs needed.

Controls are: wasd or hjkl, w/k to drop, s/j to rotate, ad/hl to move

Speed increases with score, whenever multiple lines are removed, you get the square of amount of destroyed lines

This is not the most possibly golfed solution, but i decided to golf it a little anyway. The newlines are just to fit text in 80 cols, i didn't include them in character count.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())if arg[1]then local function s(e)local e=io.popen(
"sleep "..e)e:read"*a"return e:close()end local l={{0,1,1,0,1,1},{-1,1,-1,0,1,0}
,{-1,0,1,0,1,1},{-1,0,0,1,1,0},{-1,1,0,1,1,0},{-1,0,0,1,1,1},{-1,0,1,0,2,0}}
function T(t,e,o)if o>1 then return T(-e,t,o-1)end return t,e end local t 
function fit(i,n,r,o)if n<1 or n>10 or r<1 or t[r][n]~=0 then return end for e=1
,6,2 do local e,o=T(l[i][e],l[i][e+1],o)e,o=e+n,o+r if e<1 or e>10 or o<1 or((t[
o]or{})[e]or 0)~=0 then return end end return i end function put(e,r,i,n)t[i][r]
=e for o=1,6,2 do local n,o=T(l[e][o],l[e][o+1],n)n,o=n+r,o+i;(t[o]or{})[n]=e 
end end while 1 do os.execute"clear"io.write("\27[0;37m+----------++----+\r\n"..
("|          ||    |\r\n"):rep(2)..
"|          |+----+\r\n|          |Score:\r\n"..("|          |\r\n"):rep(16)..
"+----------+\27[20F\27[C")t={}for e=1,20 do t[e]={}for o=1,10 do t[e][o]=0 end 
end local e,o,f,r,a,c,n=20,5,0,math.random(7),math.random(7),0,1 while 1 do f=f+
1 s(.1)local d=io.open(arg[1],"rb")or os.exit(0,io.write"\27[49;39m",io.stdout:
flush(),os.execute"clear")local i=d:read(1)while i do if i=="a"or i=="h"then if 
fit(r,o-1,e,n)then o=o-1 end elseif i=="d"or i=="l"then if fit(r,o+1,e,n)then o=
o+1 end elseif i=="w"or i=="k"then while fit(r,o,e-1,n)do e=e-1 end elseif i==
"s"or i=="j"then if fit(r,o,e,n+1)then n=n%4+1 end end i=d:read(1)end d:close()d
=io.open(arg[1],"w")d:write()d:close()if f%(math.max(1,10-math.floor(c/20)))==0 
then if fit(r,o,e-1,n)then e=e-1 else put(r,o,e,n)r,e,o,a,n=a,20,5,math.random(7
),1 if not fit(r,o,e,n)then break end local e=1 local o=0 while e<21 do local n=
1 for o=1,10 do n=n*t[e][o]end if n~=0 then table.remove(t,e)local e={}for o=1,
10 do e[o]=0 end table.insert(t,e)o=o+1 else e=e+1 end end c=c+o*o end end put(r
,o,e,n)for e=20,1,-1 do for o=1,10 do io.write("\27[3"..t[e][o].."m"..(t[e][o]
==0 and" "or"#"))end io.write"\27[E\27[C"end io.write("\27[20F\27[13C\27[3",a,
"m")for e=1,0,-1 do for n=-1,2 do local o for t=1,6,2 do if l[a][t]==n and l[a][
t+1]==e then io.write"#"o=e end end if e==0 and n==0 then io.write"#"o=e end if 
not o then io.write" "end end io.write"\27[4D\27[B"end io.write(
"\27[2B\27[D\27[49;37m",c,"\27[4F\27[C")t[e][o]=0 for i=1,6,2 do local r,n=T(l[r
][i],l[r][i+1],n)r,n=r+o,n+e;(t[n]or{})[r]=0 end end io.write"\27[49;39m"io.
stdout:flush()os.execute"clear"io.write
"\aGame over. Will automatically start new game in 5 seconds. Use ^C to exit"s(5
)io.stdout:flush()end else local e=os.tmpname()local o=io.open(e,"w")local n=
newproxy(true)getmetatable(n).__gc=function()os.execute"stty -raw echo"end os.
execute"stty raw -echo"local t=""i=0 while arg[i]do t=arg[i].." "..t i=i-1 end 
os.execute(t..e.." &")while 1 do o:close()local t=io.read(1)o=io.open(e,"a")o:
write(t)if t=="\3"then o:close()os.remove(e)os.execute"stty -raw echo"
getmetatable(n).__gc=nil os.execute"sleep 0.1"os.exit()end end end
```

[image: tetris in a terminal]

Comment: Do you happen to have an ungolfed version?

Comment: @nyuszika7h What do you mean? He wrote it like that using `cat`.

Comment: @CamiloMartin what's `cat`, I've been using butterfiles

Comment: @mniip Oh yeah! Good Ol' `C-x` `M-c` `M-butterfly`...

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica

This code was written in Mathematica by Xiangdong Wen and can actually be played in a web browser here: [**Shape Descender**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ShapeDescender/) (click on graphics to initiate arrows keys). Below are the screen shot and full code - which is pretty shor for a complete web app of this game.

[image]

## Code

```
allBlocks = {{{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}, {{0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}, {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}}, {{{0, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}, {{0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}, {{0, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}}, {{{0, 0, 3, 0}, {3, 3, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}, {{0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 3, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0}}, {{3, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}},
   {{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 4, 4, 0}, {0, 4, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
      0, 0}, {0, 4, 4, 0}, {0, 4, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 
      0}, {0, 4, 4, 0}, {0, 4, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 
      0}, {0, 4, 4, 0}, {0, 4, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, 0, 
      0}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 5, 
      0}, {0, 0, 5, 0}, {0, 0, 5, 0}, {0, 0, 5, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 
      0}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 5, 
      0}, {0, 0, 5, 0}, {0, 0, 5, 0}, {0, 0, 5, 0}}}, {{{6, 6, 0, 
      0}, {0, 6, 6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 6, 
      0}, {0, 6, 6, 0}, {0, 6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{6, 6, 0, 
      0}, {0, 6, 6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 6, 
      0}, {0, 6, 6, 0}, {0, 6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}}, {{{0, 7, 7, 
      0}, {7, 7, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 7, 0, 
      0}, {0, 7, 7, 0}, {0, 0, 7, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 7, 7, 
      0}, {7, 7, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 7, 0, 
      0}, {0, 7, 7, 0}, {0, 0, 7, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}}};
smallBoard = 
  Table[If[i == 1 || j == 1 || i == 6 || j == 6, 9, 0], {i, 1, 6}, {j,
     1, 6}];

color[v_] := 
  Switch[v, 0, Black, 1, Yellow, 2, Blue, 3, Magenta, 4, Cyan, 5, Red,
    6, Orange, 7, Green, 9, Gray, _, Gray];
showSquare[{i_, j_}, v_] := {color[v], 
   Rectangle[{i + 0.05, j + 0.05}, {i + 0.95, j + 0.95}]};
showHintBlock[n_, p_, x_, y_] := 
  Table[showSquare[{i + x, j + y}, allBlocks[[n, p, i, j]]], {i, 1, 
    4}, {j, 1, 4}];


initBoard[
   Hold[board_, num_]] := {board = 
    Table[If[i <= 3 || j <= 3 || i >= 14 || j >= 24, 9, 0], {i, 1, 
      16}, {j, 1, 28}], 
   Table[board[[i, 24]] = 0; board[[i, 25]] = 0; 
    board[[i, 26]] = 0, {i, 7, 10}]; 
   Table[board[[i, 25]] = 0, {i, 1, 16}]; board[[6, 25]] = 9, 
   board[[11, 25]] = 9,
   Table[If[Mod[j + i, 2] == 0, board[[j, i + 3]] = 9], {i, 1, 
     num}, {j, 4, 13}]};

bMoveTo[n_, p_, x_, y_, Hold[board_]] := 
  Total[Table[
     allBlocks[[n, p, i, j]]* board[[i + x, j + y]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1,
       4}], 2] == 0;
bGameOver[n_, p_, Hold[board_]] := 
  Not[bMoveTo[n, p, 6, 22, Hold[board]]];
bLeft[n_, p_, x_, y_, Hold[board_]] := 
  bMoveTo[n, p, x - 1, y, Hold[board]];
bRight[n_, p_, x_, y_, Hold[board_]] := 
  bMoveTo[n, p, x + 1, y, Hold[board]];
bDown[n_, p_, x_, y_, Hold[board_]] := 
  bMoveTo[n, p, x, y - 1, Hold[board]];
bRotateAnticlock[n_, p_, x_, y_, Hold[board_]] := 
 Module[{tp}, tp = p - 1; If[tp == 0, tp = 4]; 
  bMoveTo[n, tp, x, y, Hold[board]]]; 
bRotateClockwise[n_, p_, x_, y_, Hold[board_]] := 
 Module[{tp}, tp = p + 1; If[tp == 5, tp = 1]; 
  bMoveTo[n, tp, x, y, Hold[board]]];
showBoard[Hold[board_]] := 
  Table[showSquare[{i, j}, board[[i, j]]], {i, 3, 14}, {j, 3, 25}];
showDropBlock[n_, p_, x_, y_] := 
  Table[If[allBlocks[[n, p, i, j]] != 0, 
    showSquare[{i + x, j + y}, allBlocks[[n, p, i, j]]], Black], {i, 
    1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];


updateBoard[n_, p_, x_, y_, 
   Hold[board_, score_]] := {Table[
    board[[i + x, j + y]] += allBlocks[[n, p, i, j]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 
     1, 4}]; score += 
    10 + 100*(2^
         Sum[updateLine[i, Hold[board]], {i, y + 4, y + 1, -1}] - 
        1)};
updateLine[line_, Hold[board_]] := 
  If[line <= 23 && 
    line >= 4 && (Apply[And, 
       Table[board[[i, line]] != 0, {i, 4, 13}]]) == True, 
   Table[board[[i, j]] = board[[i, j + 1]], {i, 4, 13}, {j, line, 
     22}]; Table[board[[i, 23]] = 0, {i, 4, 13}]; 1, 0];
newGame[Hold[n_, p_, x_, y_, board_, nextItem_, gameOver_, pause_, 
    num_]] := {initBoard[
    Hold[board, num]]; {n, p, x, y} = {nextItem, 2, 6, 22}; 
   nextItem = RandomInteger[6] + 1; gameOver = False; pause = False};
newBlock[Hold[n_, p_, x_, y_, board_, score_, gameOver_, nextItem_, 
    pause_]] := {If[! pause && ! gameOver, 
    updateBoard[n, p, x, y, Hold[board, score]]; 
    gameOver = bGameOver[nextItem, 2, Hold[board]]; 
    If[gameOver == False, {n, p, x, y} = {nextItem, 2, 6, 22}; 
     nextItem = RandomInteger[6] + 1]]};


shapeDescend[Hold[level_, state_, num_]] := 
  DynamicModule[{score = 0, gameOver = False, pause = False, 
    board = Table[
      If[i <= 3 || j <= 3 || i >= 14 || j >= 24, 0, 0], {i, 1, 
       16}, {j, 1, 28}], n, p, x, y, nextItem}, 
   SeedRandom[level*10 + num]; nextItem = RandomInteger[6] + 1; 
   newGame[Hold[n, p, x, y, board, nextItem, gameOver, pause, num]];
   EventHandler[
    Graphics[{Text[Style["Level", Blue, Italic, 24], {18, 12}], 
      Text[Style["Score", Blue, Italic, 24], {18, 9}], 
      Table[showSquare[{i + 16, j + 13}, smallBoard[[i, j]]], {i, 1, 
        6}, {j, 1, 6}], 
      Dynamic[Refresh[
        Switch[state, 1, 
         newGame[Hold[n, p, x, y, board, nextItem, gameOver, pause, 
           num]]; state = 3,
         2, pause = True,
         3, pause = False], UpdateInterval -> Infinity, 
        TrackedSymbols -> {state}]; 
       Refresh[If[! pause && ! gameOver && 
          bDown[n, p, x, y, Hold[board]], y--, 
         newBlock[
          Hold[n, p, x, y, board, score, gameOver, nextItem, pause]]],
         UpdateInterval -> 3./level, TrackedSymbols -> {}];
       Join[{{Text[
           Style[ToString[level], Green, Italic, 24], {20, 11}], 
          Text[Style[ToString[score], Green, Italic, 24], {20, 8}]}}, 
        showBoard[Hold[board]], showDropBlock[n, p, x, y], 
        showHintBlock[nextItem, 2, 17, 14]], 
       TrackedSymbols -> {x, y, n, p, level}]}, Background -> Black, 
     ImageSize -> {400, 400}], {"LeftArrowKeyDown" :> 
      If[! pause && ! gameOver && bLeft[n, p, x, y, Hold[board]], x--],
     "RightArrowKeyDown" :> 
      If[! pause && ! gameOver && bRight[n, p, x, y, Hold[board]], 
       x++], "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (If[! pause && ! gameOver && 
         bRotateClockwise[n, p, x, y, Hold[board]], p++; 
        If[p == 5, p = 1]]), 
     "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (If[! pause && ! gameOver && 
         bRotateAnticlock[n, p, x, y, Hold[board]], p--; 
        If[p == 0, p = 4]]), {"KeyDown", " "} :> 
      If[! pause && ! gameOver && bDown[n, p, x, y, Hold[board]], y--,
        newBlock[
        Hold[n, p, x, y, board, score, gameOver, nextItem, pause]]],
     "EscapeKeyDown" :> {newGame[
        Hold[n, p, x, y, board, nextItem, gameOver, pause, num]]}}]];

Manipulate[
 shapeDescend[Hold[level, state, initLine]],
 {{level, 5}, 1, 9, 1},
 {{initLine, 3, "height of bottom level"}, 0, 9, 1},
 {{state, 3, ""}, {1 -> "new game", 2 -> "pause", 3 -> "continue"}},
 ContentSize -> {480, 450}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True, Alignment -> Center, TrackedSymbols -> {}]
```

Answer (score 5):

### C

I wrote this yeaaaaars ago while sitting bored in class in high school. Supposedly, the original programmer wrote the first version of Tetris using square brackets as blocks, and it seemed simple enough to try and recreate, no? I didn't know any GUI stuff, so I made a good, old-fashioned console program. This was back before I learned C++ and those pesky proper programming practices, so the code may be a bit messy. I pretty much just winged it.

[image: TKlone]

It meets all of the requirements of the challenge, except the piece only rotates in one direction (clockwise). Use WASD to play, W rotates the piece. The full source code and exe can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tklone/files/tklone/tklone-v1.0/

### tetris.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "defines.h"

int array[FIELD_H][FIELD_W];    //field array
int pieceCoords[2];             //current piece coordinates
int x, y;                       //looping variables
int thisPiece, nextPiece;       //current pieces
double score;                   //the players current score
int newpiece=1;                 //the newpiece flag
int init_h=1;                   /*starting coordinates of piece*/
int init_w=4;                   /*these are obsolete variables*/
int h_offset, w_offset;         //piece position offsets from start
int rtTop, rtBot, rtLeft, rtRight;  //rotation thresholds for collision
int b1h, b1w, b2h, b2w, b3h, b3w;   //block draw offsets
int rotation;                   /*0=normal view
                                  1=90 degrees clockwise
                                  2=upside-down
                                  3=270 degrees clockwise */

clock_t speed;          //time before piece falls (in milliseconds)
clock_t gravity;        //temp variable for speed

//clock_t fps;
int piececount;         //number of pieces that have fallen
int oldpiececount;
int level;


void GameInit(void);
int GameStart(void);
int GameMain(void);
void newPiece(void);

void scrollbar(void);           //scrolling marquee bar
void drawField(void);           //graphics rendering function
void setPiece(int piece);       //this sets the individual piece offsets
void drawPiece(void);           //this sets the blocks in the array
void initArray(void);           //this initializes the array
void getMoves(char move);       //input function
void rotate(int coll);          //loops from 1 to 4
int collisionCheck(int side);   //checks to see if piece will collide
int loseGame(void);             //checks to see if game has ended
void eraseLastMove(void);       //clears the array of the last move
void setLastMove(void);         //sets the piece in place for the next piece
void lineClear(void);           //clears filled lines and tabulates the score
void predict(int undo);         //predicts the next piece rotation for collision
//void delay(int duration);

int main()
{
restart:
    GameInit();
    //some test blocks
    /*for(x=FIELD_H;x>3;x--)        //quick lose pattern
        array[x][4]=1;*/

    nextPiece=rand()%7;     //generate a piece to use
    drawField();            //draw a blank field. should be a title screen
    printf("                             / Welcome to TETRIS! \\"); //29 spaces and title

    getch();            //wait to start the game

    while(1)    //main game loop
    {
        if(newpiece==1)         //check to see if a new piece is required
            newPiece();

        //if(gravity<=clock())
            gravity=speed+clock();  //get the end time
        while(gravity>clock())      //count to the end time
        {
            if(kbhit())
            {
                getMoves(getch());  //get input
                if(newpiece==1)     //if piece reaches bottom...
                    break;          //...skip by redraw to save some cycles
                else
                {
                    eraseLastMove();    //clear the last move from the array
                    drawPiece();        //set the piece in the array
                    drawField();        //refresh the screen
                    scrollbar();        //draw the scrollbar
                }
            }
        }
        if(newpiece==0)     /*minor speed optimization*/
            getMoves('s');  //force piece down a line
        eraseLastMove();    //clear the last move from the array
        drawPiece();        //set the piece in the array
        drawField();        //refresh the screen
        scrollbar();        //draw the scrollbar
    }
    return 0;
}

void GameInit()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));    //seed the random number genreator...
    initArray();                    //...and initialize the array
    //reset some variables
    score=0;
    piececount=-1;      //set to -1 because of newpiece loop on start
    oldpiececount=0;
    speed=1000;         //starting speed of piece
    level=1;
}

void newPiece()
{
    piececount++;       //another piece has fallen
    setLastMove();      //set the last move in place
    lineClear();        //clear any full lines

    newpiece=0;         //reset the newpiece flag
    rotation=0;         //reset the piece rotation
    h_offset=0;         //reset the...
    w_offset=0;         //...piece coordinates
    gravity=0;          //reset the gravity

    if(piececount-oldpiececount==10)    //if 10 more pieces have fallen
        if(speed!=200)                  //200 is the lowest speed it can go
        {
            oldpiececount=piececount;   //set current number of fallen pieces
            speed-=100;                 //make the speed faster
            level++;                    //increment the level counter
        }

    thisPiece=nextPiece;//get the current piece
    nextPiece=rand()%7; //pick the next piece

    setPiece(thisPiece);//get piece data
    if(loseGame())      //did player lose the game?
    {
        drawField();    //refresh the screen
        printf("You lose! Final score: %.0f. Press any key to begin a new game.",score);
        getch();
        newpiece=1;     //reset the newpiece flag /*add more initialization here*/
        //goto restart; //return to start of the program
        exit(0);        //quit the game for now
    }
    drawPiece();        //set the piece in the array
    drawField();        //refresh the screen
    scrollbar();        //draw the scrollbar
}

void scrollbar()
{
    //printf("================================================================================");

    printf("Score: %.0f\t\t      ",score);  //print the score (6 spaces)
    if(nextPiece==5||nextPiece==6)          //print a space if the piece name is short
        printf(" ");

    printf("Next piece: ");
    if(nextPiece==0)            //print the name of the next piece
        printf("straight");
    else if(nextPiece==1)
        printf("t-shaped");
    else if(nextPiece==2)
        printf("s-shaped");
    else if(nextPiece==3)
        printf("z-shaped");
    else if(nextPiece==4)
        printf("l-shaped");
    else if(nextPiece==5)
        printf("back-l");
    else if(nextPiece==6)
        printf("square");

    printf("\t\t\tLevel %i",level); //print the level
}

void drawField()
{
    system("cls");      //clear the screen

    for(x=0;x<FIELD_H;x++)
    {
        printf("                              |");  //thirty spaces

        for(y=0;y<FIELD_W;y++)
            if(array[x][y]==1||array[x][y]==2)
                printf("[]");
            else
                printf("  ");

        printf("|                              ");  //thirty spaces
    }

    //bottom message bar
    //scrollbar();
}

void drawPiece()
{
    /* This sets the initial location of the piece with
       movement offset. Coordinates are based on the
       center of the piece. */
    pieceCoords[0]=init_h+h_offset; //set height position
    pieceCoords[1]=init_w+w_offset; //set width position

    //mark the coordinates to draw the piece
    array[(pieceCoords[0])][(pieceCoords[1])]=2;        //center piece
    array[(pieceCoords[0]+b1h)][(pieceCoords[1]+b1w)]=2;    //other...
    array[(pieceCoords[0]+b2h)][(pieceCoords[1]+b2w)]=2;    //...three...
    array[(pieceCoords[0]+b3h)][(pieceCoords[1]+b3w)]=2;    //...pieces
}

void initArray()
{
    for(x=0;x<FIELD_H;x++)
        for(y=0;y<FIELD_W;y++)
            array[x][y]=0;
        //array equals: 0 for empty
        //              1 for full
        //              2 for moving piece
}

void getMoves(char move)
{
    switch(move)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            if(collisionCheck(1)==0)    //if the piece doesnt hit something...
                w_offset--;             //...move the piece
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            if(collisionCheck(2)==0)
                w_offset++;
            break;
        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            if(collisionCheck(0)==0)
            {
                rotate(0);              //rotate the piece and...
                setPiece(thisPiece);    //...get new piece data
            }
            break;
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            if(collisionCheck(3)==0)
                h_offset++;
            else                        //if the piece hits the bottom...
                newpiece=1;             //...set the newpiece flag
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void rotate(int coll)
{
    if(coll==0)     //rotate clockwise
    {
        if(rotation==3)
            rotation=0;
        else
            rotation++;
    }

    if(coll==1)     //rotate counterclockwise
    {
        if(rotation==0)
            rotation=3;
        else
            rotation--;
    }
}

int collisionCheck(int side)
{
    if(side==0) //check rotation collision
    {
        predict(0);

        /* For the first part, we check to see if the
           rotation will collide with the sides. */
        for(x=0;x<rtTop;x++)    //check top side collision
        {
            if(pieceCoords[0]-x==0) //if piece minus top offset hits the top
            {
                predict(1);
                return 1;   //collision detected!
            }
        }

        for(x=0;x<rtLeft;x++)   //check left side collision
        {
            if(pieceCoords[1]-x==0)
            {
                predict(1);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        for(x=0;x<rtRight;x++)  //check right side collision
        {
            if(pieceCoords[1]+x==(FIELD_W-1))
            {
                predict(1);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        for(x=0;x<rtBot;x++)    //check bottom side collision
        {
            if(pieceCoords[0]+x==(FIELD_H-1))
            {
                predict(1);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        /* Then we check to see if any of the
           blocks will hit other blocks on the field. */
        if(array[(pieceCoords[0]+b1h)][(pieceCoords[1]+b1w)]==1
    ||array[(pieceCoords[0]+b2h)][(pieceCoords[1]+b2w)]==1
    ||array[(pieceCoords[0]+b3h)][(pieceCoords[1]+b3w)]==1)
        {
            predict(1);
            return 1;
        }

        predict(1);
        return 0;
    }

    /* Here, we scan the array and check to see whether
       any of the blocks in the current piece are
       adjacent to the field sides or another block. */
    for(x=0;x<FIELD_H;x++)          //scan the array
        for(y=0;y<FIELD_W;y++)
            if(array[x][y]==2)      //if array location contains a block
            {
                if(side==1) //check left side
                {
                    if(y==0||array[x][y-1]==1)  //if piece is next to border or block...
                        return 1;   //collision detected!
                }

                else if(side==2)    //check right side
                {
                    if(y==FIELD_W-1||array[x][y+1]==1)
                        return 1;
                }

                else if(side==3)    //check bottom
                {
                    if(x==FIELD_H-1||array[x+1][y]==1)
                        return 1;
                }
            }

    return 0;
}

int loseGame()      /*need to modify the conditions of losing*/
{
    if(array[init_h][init_w]==1
||array[(init_h+b1h)][(init_w+b1w)]==1
||array[(init_h+b2h)][(init_w+b2w)]==1
||array[(init_h+b3h)][(init_w+b3w)]==1)
        return 1;

    else
        return 0;
}

void eraseLastMove()    /*need to optimize this*/
{
    for(x=0;x<FIELD_H;x++)      //scan the array
        for(y=0;y<FIELD_W;y++)
            if(array[x][y]==2)      //if the spot is filled...
                array[x][y]=0;      //...clear the block
}

void setLastMove()      /*also need to optimize this*/
{
    for(x=0;x<FIELD_H;x++)      //scan the array
        for(y=0;y<FIELD_W;y++)
            if(array[x][y]==2)      //if the spot is filled...
                array[x][y]=1;      //...set the block
}

void lineClear()
{
    int x2, y2; //new looping variables
    int empty;  //is the row empty?
    int lines=0;//number of lines cleared

    for(x=0;x<FIELD_H;x++)      //scan the rows
    {
        empty=0;                //reset the empty flag on each row

        for(y=0;y<FIELD_W;y++)  //scan the blocks in each row
            if(array[x][y]==0)  //if the row isn't full...
            {
                empty=1;        //...set the empty flag and...
                break;          //...scan the next row
            }

        if(!empty)
        {
            for(y=0;y<FIELD_W;y++)      //rescan the filled row...
                array[x][y]=0;          //...and clear the blocks

            for(x2=x-1;x2>=0;x2--)      //scan rows from the bottom up starting above cleared row
                for(y2=0;y2<FIELD_W;y2++)   //scan each block in the row
                    if(array[x2][y2]==1)
                    {
                        array[x2][y2]=0;    //clear the block
                        array[x2+1][y2]=1;  //fill in the block below it
                    }

            lines++;            //a line has been cleared
        }
    }

    //tabulate the scores
    if(lines==1)
        score+=10;
    else if(lines==2)
        score+=25;
    else if(lines==3)
        score+=50;
    else if(lines==4)   /* TETRIS! */
        score+=100;
}

void predict(int undo)
{
    if(undo==0)
    {
        rotate(0);              //get next rotation...
        setPiece(thisPiece);    //...and next piece data
    }

    if(undo==1)
    {
        rotate(1);              //un-rotate
        setPiece(thisPiece);    //reset the piece
    }
}

/*void delay(int duration)
{
    clock_t done;

    done = duration + clock();
    while(done>clock())
        ;   //sit and wait
}*/
```

### setPiece.c

```
#include "defines.h"

extern int rtTop, rtBot, rtLeft, rtRight;   //rotation thresholds for collision
extern int b1h, b1w, b2h, b2w, b3h, b3w;    //block draw offsets
extern int rotation;                    /*0=normal view
                                          1=90 degrees clockwise
                                          2=upside-down
                                          3=270 degrees clockwise */

void setPiece(int piece)
{
    if(piece==0)
    {
        switch(rotation)
        {
            case 0:     //piece looks identical rotated upside-down
            case 2:
                /* The rotation thresholds dictate how far away the piece
                   needs to be from the field edge for the next rotation. */
                rtTop=1;
                rtBot=2;
                rtLeft=0;
                rtRight=0;

                /* These are the coordinates of the
                   blocks relative to the center block. */
                b1h=-1;
                b1w=0;
                b2h=1;
                b2w=0;
                b3h=2;
                b3w=0;
                break;
            case 1:     //piece looks identical side to side
            case 3:
                rtTop=0;
                rtBot=0;
                rtLeft=1;
                rtRight=2;

                b1h=0;
                b1w=-1;
                b2h=0;
                b2w=1;
                b3h=0;
                b3w=2;
                break;
        }
    }
        //draw blue straight piece

    //snip other pieces

    else if(piece==6)
    {
        switch(rotation)
        {
            case 0:     //a cube looks identical when rotated 90 degrees
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                rtTop=0;    //piece doesn't rotate so no thresholds needed
                rtBot=0;
                rtLeft=0;
                rtRight=0;

                b1h=-1;
                b1w=0;
                b2h=-1;
                b2w=1;
                b3h=0;
                b3w=1;
                break;
        }
    }
        //draw square piece
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to PPCG. We strongly encourage answers to actually include their source code in the body of the answer, unless it is too large for the maximum post size. Even then, it is good to provide some illustrative excerpts.

Comment: Code added. setPiece.c was abbreviated slightly, and defines.h is not listed. Original code can be found at the link.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

I built a javascript version
https://marchingband.github.io/tetris/

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
      <p>q and w rotate</p>
      <p id='score'>0</p>
      <div id='board' style='position:absolute;top:80px' ></div>
  </body>
</html>
  <script>
    var pieceIndex=0
    nextPiece=()=>{
      pieceIndex=pieceIndex<pieces.length-1?pieceIndex+1:0
      return pieces[pieceIndex]
    }
    const pieces=[
    [
        {x:0,y:-1},
        {x:0,y:0},
        {x:1,y:0},
        {x:-1,y:0},
      ],
      [
        {x:0,y:-2},
        {x:0,y:-1},
        {x:0,y:0},
        {x:0,y:1},
      ],
      [
        {x:1,y:0},
        {x:0,y:0},
        {x:2,y:0},
        {x:0,y:-1},
      ],
      [
        {x:0,y:0},
        {x:1,y:0},
        {x:1,y:1},
        {x:0,y:1}
      ],
      [
        {x:0,y:0},
        {x:-1,y:0},
        {x:0,y:1},
        {x:1,y:1}
      ],
    ]
    const speeds =[1000,800,600,400,300,250,200,150,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20]
    const boardWidth = 10
    const boardHeight = 20
    const pixelSize   = 10
    const pixelBorder = 0
    const boardBorder = 5
    
    var score = 0
    var level = 0
    var fallingBits = []

    const b = document.getElementById('board')
     piece = {
      position:{
        x:boardWidth/2,
        y:1,
      },
      bits:[
        {x:0,y:-1},
        {x:0,y:0},
        {x:1,y:0},
        {x:-1,y:0},
      ],
      reset(){
        piece.position={x:boardWidth/2,y:1}
        piece.bits=nextPiece()
        !piece.coordinates().every((b)=>dom[b.x][b.y]?dom[b.x][b.y].style.background=='red':true) && endGame()
      },
      coordinates(){
        return piece.bits.map((b)=>{
          return {x:b.x+piece.position.x,y:b.y+piece.position.y}
        })
      }
    }
    const dom = []
    for(var x=0;x<boardWidth;x++){
      var row = []
      for(var y=0;y<boardHeight;y++){
        var cell = document.createElement('div')
        cell.style.cssText='outline:thin solid;height:'+pixelSize+'px;width:'+pixelSize+'px;background:red;position:absolute'
        cell.style.left= (x*(pixelSize+pixelBorder)+boardBorder) + 'px'
        cell.style.top = (y*(pixelSize+pixelBorder)+boardBorder) + 'px'
        row.push(cell)
        b.appendChild(cell)
      }
      dom.push(row)
    }
    renderPiece=(color)=>{
      piece.coordinates().forEach((b)=>dom[b.x][b.y] && (dom[b.x][b.y].style.background=color))
    }
    drop=()=>{
      piece.coordinates().every((p)=>p.y+1<boardHeight) && piece.coordinates().every((p)=>dom[p.x][p.y+1].style.background!='blue') ?
        movePiece(0,1) : freeze()
    }
    strafe=(d)=>{
      piece.coordinates().every((p)=>p.x+d<boardWidth && p.x+d >=0) && piece.coordinates().every((p)=>dom[p.x+d][p.y].style.background!='blue') ?
        movePiece(d,0) : null
    }
    freeze=()=>{
      piece.coordinates().forEach((p)=>dom[p.x][p.y].style.background='blue')
      lookForRows()
      piece.reset()
    }
    lookForRows=()=>{
      [...dom[0].keys()].filter((i)=>dom.every((c)=>c[i].style.background=='blue')).forEach((r)=>{
        removeLine(r)
        compressAbove(r)
        addPoint()
      })
    }
    compressAbove=(r)=>{
      // dom.reduce((acc,col,x)=>{return acc.concat(col.map((b,y)=>{return {x:x,y:y}}).filter((b,y)=>y<r && dom[b.x][b.y].style.background=='blue'))},[]).forEach((b)=>dom[b.x][b.y].style.background='red').forEach((b)=>dom[b.x][b.y+1].style.background='blue')
      var bits = []
      dom.forEach((x,i)=>{
        x.forEach((y,j)=>{
          if(j<=r && dom[i][j].style.background=='blue'){bits.push({x:i,y:j})}
        })
      })
      bits.forEach((b)=>{
        dom[b.x][b.y].style.background='red'
      })
      bits.forEach((b)=>{
        dom[b.x][b.y+1].style.background='blue'
      })
    }
    removeLine=(r)=>{
      dom.forEach((x)=>x[r].style.background='red')
    }
    changePiece=(x,y)=>{
      piece.position.x += x
      piece.position.y += y
    }
    movePiece=(x,y)=>{
        renderPiece('red')
        changePiece(x,y)
        renderPiece('yellow')
    }
    turn=(d)=>{
      var newBits = []
      for(let i=0;i<piece.bits.length;i++){
        var x = piece.bits[i].x
        var y = piece.bits[i].y
        var bit={}
        if(d==1){
          bit.x=-y
          bit.y=x
        }else{
          bit.x=y
          bit.y=-x
        }
        newBits.push(bit)
      }
      if(newBits.every((p)=>p.x+piece.position.x<boardWidth && p.x+piece.position.x>=0 && p.y+piece.position.y<boardHeight && dom[p.x+piece.position.x][p.y+piece.position.y].style.background!='blue')){
        renderPiece('red')
        piece.bits=newBits
        renderPiece('yellow')
      }
    }
    addPoint=()=>{
      score++
      document.getElementById('score').innerText=score
      score-level*10 > 10 && levelUp()
    }
    levelUp=()=>{
      clearInterval(timer)
      level++
      timer = window.setInterval(drop,speeds[level])
    }
    endGame=()=>{
      clearInterval(timer)
      dom.forEach((row)=>{
        row.forEach((bit)=>{
          bit.style.background=='red' && (bit.style.background='black')
        })
      })
    }
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:strafe(-1);break
        case 87:turn(1);break
        case 81:turn(-1);break
        case 39:strafe(1);break
        case 40:drop();break
    }
};
  var timer = window.setInterval(drop,1000)
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice one. Unfortunately has a small bug in Firefox, where all pieces fall until the bottom of the pit, because `dom[p.x][p.y+1].style.background` returns `blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%`, so will never equal `blue`. Your solution is valid, but I would suggest to change all `.style.background` → `.style.backgroundColor` to work fine both in Firefox and Chrome.