# Generate the outline of an island from a seed

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output

The challenge is to draw the outline of an 'island', generated using a seed as input.

- Input (seed): string of 6 characters (exactly) allowing only lowercase letters (i.e. abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) - examples: 'island', 'aaaaaa', 'jhgcfj'
- Each seed is to give a unique island (i.e. no two seeds will give the same output)
- No output is to be a transformation of another seed's output. That's translation, reflection, rotation, scaling or any combination thereof.
- Using the same seed should always give the same output
- Output: 600px by 600px image

A valid island is drawn using a single line, which:

- forms a closed loop
- is 1px thick with no smoothing, blurring etc.
- is continuous (i.e. after drawing a pixel the next pixel will be in one of the 8 adjoining spaces that isn't occupied)
- does not cross itself at any point
- does not leave the boundaries of the image
- is black (#000), on a background of white (#FFF)
- has no lines of reflective symmetry
- must enclose white space

Source code has a limit of 500 bytes.

Aside from that, popularity decides; most votes wins.

Comment: I think that, in this case, [tag:popularity-contest] is being used as a cover for an incomplete spec. I do think you're on to something here - I haven't seen many challenges that require a seed as input and something cool as output. The part that really needs work is "there are no specific criteria". If you want community's help settling on some solid criteria, you could post your question to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/18487).

Comment: This seems way too broad and is also more of an art contest than a programming contest. As it stands, almost any code which produces some blob of colour could be sold as an "island".

Comment: You might draw some inspiration from [Polygonal Map Generation for Games](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/). The entire process may be a little too broad, but you could narrow it down.

Comment: Maybe not an *exact* duplicate of [Paralell projected voxel terrain generator](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22439/paralell-projected-voxel-terrain-generator), but anyone editing to make it less broad should take a look at that one to avoid *making* it a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have edited the question and tried to improve the criteria.

Comment: What exactly approximates the outline of a natural island? They come in all shapes and sizes, from specks in the water to entire continents. It seems like almost any simple closed loop fits. Right now this just reads like "draw a black line that loops and doesn't cross" to me.

Comment: I like this question! I voted to close so we don't have people answering it since it seems like we are still discussing the spec. This question could have benefited from the sandbox, but I think we can still improve it and reopen it.

Comment: Overhauled the rules and changed to code golf

Comment: i really think this should be a popularity contest.

Comment: @proudhaskeller why? wouldn't that make it an art contest? With tight constraints, I think it might work well as code-golf. I also thought we were supposed to avoid popularity contests when possible.

Comment: @chilemagic never mind what others think, what do you think? I think the very nature of the question "draw an island" is subjective. People are likely to vote for short code that draws a realistic island (if it's a codegolf, someone will draw a star and people will complain it doesn't look like an island.) I have frequently advocated changing popularity contest to codegolf, but for certain graphical questions I think an exception should be made.

Comment: @steveverrill a star would break the "has no lines of reflective symmetry" rule. If people are going to vote for short code that draws a realistic island, then I think it would make sense to make `code-golf` and the requirements for what constitutes a realistic island would have to be clearly laid out (which I think the current rules may already be enough to avoid allowing loophole islands). If the question is to generically "draw an island", it becomes too broad/an art contest. It would make sense to me to make it code-golf and I wanted to understand the perspective for a popularity-contest.

Comment: @chilemagic, the current rules have some easy loopholes. As a code golf this would need a major overhaul to generate anything which looks remotely natural, and as a pop-con it's still so loosely specified that it looks more like an art contest than a programming contest.

Comment: @PeterTaylor that makes sense. Maybe there could be a byte limit to make it more of a programming challenge, and let the popularity decide which island looks the most natural. Just trying to throw out some thoughts, I would like to see some nicely generated islands though!

Comment: @chilemagic that sounds a very good idea. If others think so too, I would recommend  about 500 bytes.

Comment: Added byte limit

Comment: Is there anything I can do to have this taken off hold or is the question dead?

Answer (score 3):

## BBC basic

Here's a very simple algorithm, which could be refined for more realism. If there are further changes in the rules I'm willing to change / delete.

take the 6 character string and add `}@` to ensure asymmetry (this particular choice of characters gives islands that vaguely resemble Antarctica)

draw a line that connects 8 points at 45 degree intervals, with distance from the centre determined by the ASCII code.

```
  INPUT a$
  a$=a$+"}@"
  MOVE 364,300
  FOR i=1 TO 8
    r=4*ASC(MID$(a$,i))-192
    DRAW 300+r*COS(i*PI/4),300+r*SIN(i*PI/4)
  NEXT
```

[image]

Comment: @BetaDecay Black-on-white is required by the spec.

Comment: There are still outputs who are variations of each other - @}zzaa and @}aazz are reflections of each other

Comment: @proudhaskeller @ and } are not allowed in the input. That is why they were chosen to be added to the input before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

## [Algoid](http://www.algoid.net)

Algoid is a language similar to LOGO or Turtle and is *almost* entirely graphics based.

```
algo.hide()
algo.setBgColor(15)
algo.setStroke(1)
algo.setColor(0)
algo.goTo(-400,100)
set seed="put seed here".lower()
set letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set sides=seed.length()
for (set i=0;i<sides-(sides/6);i++) {
    set letter = seed.getChar(i%seed.length())
    set value = letters.indexOf(letter)*5
    set turn = 360/seed.length()
    algo.go(math.sin(value)*(1500/seed.length()))
    algo.turnRight(turn)
}
algo.lineTo(-400,100)
```

### Seed: `supercalifragilisticexpialiadocious even though the sound of it is rather quite atrocious`

[image]

### Seed: `islands in the stream`

[image]