# Tetris, Here We Go Again

Tags: code-golf, tetris

## Code Golfed Tetris

Inspired by a [popularity-question](/questions/tagged/popularity-question)  [(Re)Implementing Tetris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/reimplementing-tetris) and a [challenge on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858384/code-golf-playing-tetris) 3 years ago *when PCG did not yet exist*, the classy tetris has yet to live again in the art-work of PCG's golfers. So here are the features:

### Required:

- Game must be playable.
- Playfield or blocks are 10 in width and 20 in height
- Complete [7 tetrominoes](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Tetromino) are involved
- Controls on the current tetromino: Right and Left Navigator, Tetromino rotator (*Can be only clockwise*), & Hard drop.

### Bonuses:

- **-50** Distinguished color for each tetromino
- **-50** Distinguished texture for each tetromino
  [image]

*Provide a photo of the output for those who can't emulate it*

Comment: There's potential for a really good question here, but as it stands the spec is way too loose. Your bonuses aren't worth the effort because, for example, adding a menu will cost more than 35 characters in any language so it's cheaper to leave it out. I think it would be better to be more strict about what you do and do not want in the entries, and skip the bonuses.

Comment: It's always better to be strict about what you do and don't want and skip the bonuses.

Comment: `must have a reasonable distribution of tetrimnoes` What does this mean? Is this just protecting against http://xkcd.com/221/ ?

Comment: nope, reasonable in a way that it's variation is supplied for the player to have all 7 tetromino at least every 14 distribution.

Comment: @Daniel Are you saying that you want the program to skew the random results to FORCE a distribution? If so that should seriously be put into the question. (NVM, I see that you did). This leads to the question, is this the only restriction on producing tetriminos? If I assign them an ID and pick it with (++curID)%7 would that be valid?

Comment: yes, that's my point, but I think that requirement is just way to obvious or normal for tetris game, I'm gonna remove it

Comment: "different texture for every tetromino" : Since most answers will be ASCII art, I assume this is just using a different symbol for every tetromino.

Comment: Is this challenge still available? Or has it just been abandoned?