# Given a list of circles, output the area of the smallest containing rectangle

Tags: code-golf, math, optimization

You will be given a list of radii, you must output the area of the smallest rectangle which they will all fit in.

For example, given the list `[5,3,1.5]` you would output `157.460`.

This is the image:

[image]

The width is 15.7460 and the height is 10, so the area is 157.460

Rules:

- You get the list via stdin or function argument, output the answer via stdout or function return.
- The radii will have at most 2 decimal places.
- The list will have a length between 2 and 6.
- The output should be accurate to 3 decimal places or more.
- If you need, π = 3.1416.

Test cases:

- `[5,3,1.5] = 157.460`
- `[9,4,8,2] = 733.431` - [working here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9IwO.jpg).
- `[18,3,1] = 1296.000`

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40201/circle-packing-in-a-rectangle)

Comment: i don't see an objective winning criterion

Comment: that's one of our most central rules

Comment: @Tim Most are code golf, with the goal of coding it in the fewest bytes. I think this would make a good code golf challenge, as it has an exact spec.

Comment: I recommend getting rid of the "rounded not truncated" condition because it's peripheral to the task, and some languages can just do it while others need extra coding to make it happen. I'm not sure if you intend it to be OK to output more than 3 decimal places, but I'd suggest allowing that too.

Comment: @xnor I've gone for code golf, although I'm a little worried it's too tricky to get exact answers. And yes, updated the 3dp thing. Do you think "Into your program, try the three test cases. Your score is the absolute difference between the sum of the three test cases your code outputs, and the correct sum - 2186.891. This means you are aiming for a score of 0." would be suitable / better?

Comment: @Tim It's on the harder side for a golf challenge, but I think that's fine. I expect many answers to try to brute force all packings to get the optimum and be really inefficient in run-time. Some larger test cases would be nice if you can generate them, in particular the upper limit of 6.

Comment: @xnor I would love to, but I'm making these by hand. I'll attempt a 6 one, but each circle added makes my wolfram alpha time increase dramatically.

Comment: @xnor [More test cases](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136042/39242)! :-)

Answer (score 17):

## Python 2 + [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt), 267 bytes

```python
from pyscipopt import*
R=input()
m=Model()
V,C=m.addVar,m.addCons
a,b,c=V(),V(),V()
m.setObjective(c)
C(a*b<=c)
P=[]
for r in R:
 x,y=V(),V();C(r<=x);C(x<=a-r);C(r<=y);C(y<=b-r)
 for u,v,s in P:C((x-u)**2+(y-v)**2>=(r+s)**2)
 P+=(x,y,r),
m.optimize()
m.printBestSol()
```

#### How it works

We write the problem as follows: minimize *c* over variables *a*, *b*, *c*, *x*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>1</sub>, …, *x*<sub>*n*</sub>, *y*<sub>*n*</sub>, where

- *ab* ≤ *c*;
- *r*<sub>*i*</sub> ≤ *x*<sub>*i*</sub> ≤ *a* − *r*<sub>*i*</sub> and *r*<sub>*i*</sub> ≤ *y*<sub>*i*</sub> ≤ *b* − *y*<sub>*i*</sub>, for 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*;
- (*x*<sub>*i*</sub> − *x*<sub>*j*</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*y*<sub>*i*</sub> − *y*<sub>*j*</sub>)<sup>2</sup> ≥ (*r*<sub>*i*</sub> + *r*<sub>*j*</sub>)<sup>2</sup>, for 1 ≤ *j* < *i* ≤ *n*.

Obviously, we’re using an external optimization library on these constraints, but you can’t just feed them to any old optimizer—even Mathematica’s `NMinimize` gets stuck at local minima for these tiny test cases.  If you stare closely at the constraints, you’ll see that they constitute a [quadratically-constrained quadratic program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program), and finding the global optimum for a non-convex QCQP is NP-hard.  So we need some incredibly high-powered magic.  I chose the industrial-strength solver [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/), which is the only global QCQP solver I could find with so much as a free license for academic use.  Happily, it has some very nice Python bindings.

#### Input and output

Pass the radius list on stdin, like `[5,3,1.5]`.  The output shows `objective value:` rectangle area, `x1`, `x2` rectangle dimensions, `x3` rectangle area again, `x4`, `x5` first circle center coordinates, `x6`, `x7` second circle center coordinates, etc.

#### Test cases

#### `[5,3,1.5]` ↦ `157.459666673757`

[image: 5,3,1.5]

```python
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 0.04
Solving Nodes      : 187
Primal Bound       : +1.57459666673757e+02 (9 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +1.57459666673757e+02
Gap                : 0.00 %
objective value:                     157.459666673757
x1                                                 10   (obj:0)
x2                                   15.7459666673757   (obj:0)
x3                                   157.459666673757   (obj:1)
x4                                                  5   (obj:0)
x5                                                  5   (obj:0)
x6                                                  7   (obj:0)
x7                                   12.7459666673757   (obj:0)
x8                                                1.5   (obj:0)
x9                                   10.4972522849871   (obj:0)
```

#### `[9,4,8,2]` ↦ `709.061485909243`

This is better than the OP’s solution.  The exact dimensions are 18 by 29 + 6√3.

[image: 9,4,8,2]

```python
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 1.07
Solving Nodes      : 4650
Primal Bound       : +7.09061485909243e+02 (6 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +7.09061485909243e+02
Gap                : 0.00 %
objective value:                     709.061485909243
x1                                                 18   (obj:0)
x2                                   39.3923047727357   (obj:0)
x3                                   709.061485909243   (obj:1)
x4                                                  9   (obj:0)
x5                                   30.3923047727357   (obj:0)
x6                                                 14   (obj:0)
x7                                   18.3923048064677   (obj:0)
x8                                                  8   (obj:0)
x9                                                  8   (obj:0)
x10                                                 2   (obj:0)
x11                                  19.6154311552252   (obj:0)
```

#### `[18,3,1]` ↦ `1295.999999999`

[image: 18,3,1]

```python
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 0.00
Solving Nodes      : 13
Primal Bound       : +1.29599999999900e+03 (4 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +1.29599999999900e+03
Gap                : 0.00 %
objective value:                       1295.999999999
x1                                   35.9999999999722   (obj:0)
x2                                                 36   (obj:0)
x3                                     1295.999999999   (obj:1)
x4                                   17.9999999999722   (obj:0)
x5                                                 18   (obj:0)
x6                                   32.8552571627738   (obj:0)
x7                                                  3   (obj:0)
x8                                                  1   (obj:0)
x9                                                  1   (obj:0)
```

#### Bonus cases

#### `[1,2,3,4,5]` ↦ `230.244214912998`

[image: 1,2,3,4,5]

```python
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 401.31
Solving Nodes      : 1400341
Primal Bound       : +2.30244214912998e+02 (16 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +2.30244214912998e+02
Gap                : 0.00 %
objective value:                     230.244214912998
x1                                   13.9282031800476   (obj:0)
x2                                    16.530790960676   (obj:0)
x3                                   230.244214912998   (obj:1)
x4                                                  1   (obj:0)
x5                                   9.60188492354373   (obj:0)
x6                                    11.757778088743   (obj:0)
x7                                   3.17450418828415   (obj:0)
x8                                                  3   (obj:0)
x9                                    13.530790960676   (obj:0)
x10                                  9.92820318004764   (obj:0)
x11                                   12.530790960676   (obj:0)
x12                                                 5   (obj:0)
x13                                                 5   (obj:0)
```

#### `[3,4,5,6,7]` ↦ `553.918025310597`

[image: 3,4,5,6,7]

```python
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 90.28
Solving Nodes      : 248281
Primal Bound       : +5.53918025310597e+02 (18 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +5.53918025310597e+02
Gap                : 0.00 %
objective value:                     553.918025310597
x1                                   21.9544511351279   (obj:0)
x2                                   25.2303290086403   (obj:0)
x3                                   553.918025310597   (obj:1)
x4                                                  3   (obj:0)
x5                                   14.4852813557912   (obj:0)
x6                                   4.87198593295855   (obj:0)
x7                                   21.2303290086403   (obj:0)
x8                                   16.9544511351279   (obj:0)
x9                                                  5   (obj:0)
x10                                                 6   (obj:0)
x11                                                 6   (obj:0)
x12                                  14.9544511351279   (obj:0)
x13                                  16.8321595389753   (obj:0)
```

#### `[3,4,5,6,7,8]` ↦ `777.87455544487`

[image: 3,4,5,6,7,8]

```python
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 218.29
Solving Nodes      : 551316
Primal Bound       : +7.77874555444870e+02 (29 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +7.77874555444870e+02
Gap                : 0.00 %
objective value:                      777.87455544487
x1                                   29.9626413867546   (obj:0)
x2                                   25.9614813640722   (obj:0)
x3                                    777.87455544487   (obj:1)
x4                                   13.7325948669477   (obj:0)
x5                                   15.3563780595534   (obj:0)
x6                                   16.0504838821134   (obj:0)
x7                                   21.9614813640722   (obj:0)
x8                                   24.9626413867546   (obj:0)
x9                                   20.7071098175984   (obj:0)
x10                                                 6   (obj:0)
x11                                  19.9614813640722   (obj:0)
x12                                                 7   (obj:0)
x13                                                 7   (obj:0)
x14                                  21.9626413867546   (obj:0)
x15                                  8.05799919177801   (obj:0)
```

Comment: Shame the last one gives a slight rounding error, but nice work!

Comment: It looks to me like [1,2,3,4,5] could be improved by making the radius 3 and radius 5 circles touch also, then rotating the radius 4 / radius 5 diagonal clockwise slightly (the radius 1 circle would have to be moved out of the way but there is plenty of dead space for that. Both my instinct and my calculations indicate that a long, thin rectangle can contain the radius 4/ radius 5 circles more efficiently than a squarer one.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I don’t agree. Moving 3 up to touch 5 would push 4 away to the right (counterclockwise from 5), not let it move left (clockwise from 5). My program’s configuration is (7 + 4√3) × (9 + √(29 + 16√3)) ≈ 13.9282 × 16.5308 ≈ 230.244, while your suggested configuration is (30 + 15√3)/4 × (36 + 3√5 + 6√15)/4 ≈ 13.9952 × 16.4865 ≈ 230.732.