# Tic-Tac-Toe - X or O?

Tags: code-golf, board-game, classification, tic-tac-toe

## Background

<sup>Skip to "Task" if you are familiar with Tic-Tac-Toe (I think most are!)</sup>

[Tic-Tac-Toe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) is a famous two-player game. It consists of a **3x3** board that is filled gradually by two players (clarifications below); The first player uses the character `X` and the other one uses `O`. The winner is the first to get 3 consecutive and identical characters (`X` or `O`), either horizontally, vertically or diagonally. In case the board is filled and none of the players managed to get three consecutive characters as decribed above, the game ends in a tie. Note that there might be empty spots at the end of the game, in case either of the players wins in less than 9 moves in total (this cannot happen in case of a tie).

## Task

Given a Tic-Tac-Toe board at the end of a game (in the form of a string, a matrix, a flat list of 9 ordered values, any other decent format), determine who wins the game.

- The input will consist of distinct and *consistent* values, one for `X`, one for `O` and another one that represents an empty spot.
- Your program should be able to output 3 distinct, consistent and non-empty values: one in case `X` wins, another one in case `O` wins or another if the players are tied.

  Please specify these values in your answer. You can assume that the input will be a valid Tic-Tac-Toe board.

## Test Cases

`X`, `O`, `_` are the input values here; `X wins`, `O wins` and `Tie` are for the output.

```
X O X
O X _
O _ X
```

Output: `X wins`.

```
X _ O
X O _
X O X
```

Output: `X wins`.

```
X O X
_ O X
_ O _
```

Output: `O wins`.

```
X O X
O O X
X X O
```

Output: `Tie`.

---

As usual, all our standard rules apply. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes in every language wins!

Comment: Get out of my brain! Literally just had an idea for a Noughts & Crosses challenge that I was gonna Sanbox on Monday. Then I crack open the site and see this!

Comment: @Shaggy To cite someone from the "Fast and Furious" series: *Too slow!* ;p

Comment: It's OK, my idea was for a playable version, assuming that hasn't been done already.

Comment: @Laikoni I don't think it's a dupe, since this has way more flexible input and output and also has empty boxes too, and this also lets you assume the input is a valid board.

Comment: [Playing the game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/noughts-and-crosses-aka-tic-tac-toe) is a harder challenge, which obviously involves testing for winning and tied conditions.

Comment: @Joshua That’s about making a Tic-tac-toe game. This is about grading one.

Comment: @Joshua Apart from the very idea of Tic-Tac-Toe, this has nothing to do with that one. And that shouldn't be a problem anyway since we have a [tag:tic-tac-toe] tag :-)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Read dmkee's comment. That's what I acted on.

Comment: This should be reopened—it’s different enough from the alleged duplicates

Comment: @Titus Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: Could you add a test case where either X or O wins with a diagonal from the top-right to the bottom-left? I succeeded in all test cases, but had only added a check for the top-left to bottom-right diagonal instead of both.

Comment: What if we don't know who wins? Say, the input is an empty board.

Comment: @Soaku Consider reading the *Task* section again. The empty board is NOT *a valid board *at the end of a game**

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I will add one later, thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder that's true, sorry. I didn't understood what you meant by "at the end of a game", now I get it.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>16 15</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
U,Z;ŒD$€ẎḄỊÐḟḢ
```

A monadic link accepting a list of lists (the rows - or columns) with the values:

```
X = 0.155; O = -0.155; _ = 0
```

Returning results:

```
X wins = 1.085; O wins = -1.085; Tie = 0
```

Note: using a value of zero for `_`, and equal but opposite values for `X` and `O`, this value (here `0.155`) may be in the range `(1/6, 1/7)` (exclusive at both ends) - I only chose a value in that range that gave a precisely representable floating point result for the win cases.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9UJ8r66CQXlUdNax7u6nu4o@Xh7q7DEx7umP9wx6L///9HRyvoGZqa6iggU7E6XArRCkBgoKOgS4x4LAA)**

#### How?

```
U,Z;ŒD$€ẎḄỊÐḟḢ - Link: list of lists (as described above)
U              - upend (reverse each row)
  Z            - transpose (get the columns)
 ,             - pair the two
      $€       - last two links as a monad for each of them:
    ŒD         -   diagonals (leading diagonals - notes: 1. only one is of length 3;
               -              2. the upend means we get the anti-diagonals too)
   ;           -   concatenate (with the rows/columns)
        Ẏ      - tighten (make a single list of all the rows, columns and diagonals)
         Ḅ     - from binary (vectorises) (note that [0.155, 0.155, 0.155]
               -                           converts to 4*0.155+2*0.155+1*0.155 = 1.085
               -                           and [-0.155, -0.155, -0.155]
               -                           converts to 4*-0.155+2*-0.155+1*-0.155 = -1.085
               -                           while shorter lists or those of length three
               -                           with any other mixtures of 0.155, -0.155 and 0
               -                           yield results between -1 and 1
               -                           e.g. [.155,.155,0] -> 0.93)
           Ðḟ  - filter discard if:
          Ị    -   insignificant (if abs(z) <= 1) (discards all non-winning results)
             Ḣ - head (yields the first value from the list or zero if it's empty)
```

Comment: Yes, I think any esoteric language answers should have an explanation (and I like to see explanations for normal languages too!)

Comment: Thanks for adding it! Very good approach, way more clever than what I've though of... Nice

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>103</s> 87 bytes

```js
a=>"012+345+678+036+147+258+048+246T".replace(/\d/g,n=>a[n]||!1).match(/(\d)\1\1|T/)[0]
```

### Input

- X is represented as `1`
- O is represented as `2`
- _ is represented as `0`

### Output

- X wins is represented as `"111"`
- O wins is represented as `"000"`
- Tie is represented as `"T"`

### Explanation

```
a=>
    "012+345+678+036+147+258+048+246" // List of indexes for each row
    .replace(/\d/g,n=>a[n]||!1)       // Replace all digits with the value of the cell
    .match(/(\d)\1\1|$/)[0]           // Find the first row filled with the same value
```

### Test cases

```js
f=
a=>"012+345+678+036+147+258+048+246T".replace(/\d/g,n=>a[n]||!1).match(/(\d)\1\1|T/)[0]
console.log(f([1,2,1,2,1,0,2,0,1]))
console.log(f([1,0,2,1,2,0,1,2,1]))
console.log(f([1,2,1,0,2,1,0,2,0]))
console.log(f([1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2]))
```

Comment: "Your program should be able to output 3 distinct, consistent and **non-empty values**", so you can't output empty string for tie.

Comment: @Soaku My bad, I missed that part of the rules.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
UŒD;;Z;ŒDµSA⁼3µÐfḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/06CQXa@soayB1aGuw46PGPcaHth6ekPZwx6L///9HRysY6ijoArGCYawOl0K0LipXAcwECcXGAgA)

`X` = `1`, `O` = `-1`, `_` = `0`
X wins = `[1, 1, 1]`, O wins = `[-1, -1, -1]`, Tie = `0`
Input as list of 3 lists of 3 elements in `(1, -1, 0)` each.

Comment: Wow Nice... When you are done golfing, please add the I/O values and an explanation :-)

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJJeHOxaFc4Uebre2jrI@3H5oa43@o6Y1D3c2/f//PzpawVBHwUhHwTBWh0shGsRCcIAyIMnYWAA) is a similar approach with a slightly shorter test. Takes `X`=`1`, `O`=`2`, `_`=`3`, returns `1` (X wins), `2` (O wins) or `3` (tie).

Comment: @Arnauld thanks for the shortening

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 70 bytes

```php
for($c=95024101938;${${$i++&7}.=$argn[$c%9]}=1<$c/=3;);echo$XXX-$OOO;
```

Assumes `-n` (interpreter defaults). Additionally requires `-R` (execute `<code>` for every line of input), counted as one.

Input is taken on a single line (exactly as in the problem description, except with all whitespace removed).

Output is the following: `1` → X Wins, `-1` → O Wins, `0` → Tie .

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfkFGgoJsXpP4/Lb9IQyXZ1tLUwMjE0MDQ0tjCWqUaCDO1tdXMa/VsVRKL0vOiVZJVLWNrbQ1tVJL1bY2tNa1TkzPyVSIiInRV/P39rf@r/4/wB8J4//gIAA)

Comment: You do not need to have the whole strings, you can choose your output values. `'X Wins'` can be changed to `'X'` (or even an integer -- say `1`). The same applies to `'O wins'` and `Tie`. That being said, [109 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcSxDoIwFEDR3a/o8GLaoEZcSKwNi4uLHXRoQpCUUuCFwAN0M/y6ldycO7ZjCJe0pplDqerZ24o/ntfbfRcnQsJ3DbfJclBQZjRX3L7AKdv01nnrHVKDHaLvpp6mqc8AoygX@aLASSG9awmMMenxzEFrncbnk5AhGKaZ2axYsb5g5kfjB2l4h/3wBw).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 58 bytes

**56 bytes code + 2 fpr `-p0`.**

```perl
$_=eval sprintf'/(.)(.{%s}\1){2}/s||'x4 .'0?$1:T',0,2..4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBCoMwEETv@xUSUqJgExW9tJR@wl562IOw9KAgSBKMlIL6602tPbyBeTDju2lsYu@mJA1@HGbT2taaXHK2RMm37vUck@Cnwc69MqnOUr2cwtaW2VJtJqyreteJVsVdlpeHyou80rqOVzgWQjKIDfYbISIhARIDMgEQIxAy/OQRfMD/gjtE@HF@HpwN8eyLLw)

Outputs `X` and `O` for wins, or `T` for a tie. Includes a bunch of header/footer code to test all at once.

---

### Alternative, 58 bytes

```perl
$}.="/(.)(.{$_}\\1){2}/s||"for 0,2..4;$_=eval$}.'0?$1:T'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvBCoMwEETv@xUlBFSwiUq9VKSfsJce9hBYerAgSAwqvcT8etNoD29ghjduWKY2vuflkq9uGjdtrLG6lFz4KIPqhc5VkSsvORhTF74Jet13cRyqslHq1knuh89rSnJWPWR9f2axA7eMdhOSQQRIghCRkACJAZkAiBEIGY7xDD7hf8EEEX5nt42zXePVVT8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes

```python
lambda b:{'XXX','OOO'}&{*b.split(),b[::4],b[1::4],b[2::4],b[::5],b[2::3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHJqlo9IiJCXUfd399fvVatWitJr7ggJ7NEQ1MnKdrKyiQWSBlCaSMobWVlCuUax9b@LyjKzCvRUEjTUI/wj4jJ84@IBxLxEeqaCppcSHLx/jF5Ef7xIAJDDqQvHkLEY5PzBxEREf4guf8A)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>100</s> <s>95</s> <s>92</s> <s>87</s> <s>82</s> 77 bytes

```python
lambda b:{'XXX','OOO'}&set(b.split()+[b[::4],b[1::4],b[2::4],b[::5],b[2::3]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYtBCsIwEEX3PUVXToKlYNVNwDPMdiAJQ4MWCzUNNhuRnj0aDAi6eY/P44dHvM6@S8PJpKm/uXNfO/UEIoIGEBHWzXKJwrVLmMYo5FY7rdTBNk7virtipY5l7q2VKdxHH@tBACEZj8RvMIGsqm9hNJ6QM35K/vAH/F8wgwhBphc)

---

Takes input as a newline separated string of `XO_`

Outputs:

- `{'XXX'}` for `X`,
- `{'OOO'}` for `O`
- `{}` for a tie

Works by slicing the string into rows columns and diagonals:

```python
The board:
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9
which is '123\n456\n789' is sliced into:

['123', '456', '789', '147', '258', '369', '159', '357']
rows: b.split() -> ['123', '456', '789']
cols: [b[::4],b[1::4],b[2::4]] -> ['147', '258', '369']
diag: [b[::5],b[2::3]] -> ['159', '357']
```

then `'XXX'` and `'OOO'` are checked against the slices.

Takes input as a newline separated string of `XO_`

Outputs:

- `{'XXX'}` for `X`,
- `{'OOO'}` for `O`
- `{}` for a tie

Works by slicing the string into rows columns and diagonals:

```python
The board:
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9
which is '123\n456\n789' is sliced into:

['123', '456', '789', '147', '258', '369', '159', '357']
rows: b.split() -> ['123', '456', '789']
cols: [b[::4],b[1::4],b[2::4]] -> ['147', '258', '369']
diag: [b[::5],b[2::3]] -> ['159', '357']
```

then `'XXX'` and `'OOO'` are checked against the slices.

Comment: Python slicing FTW Anyways, [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHJqlo9IiJCXUfd399fvVatOinayjhWJyna2MoMRJlZgUgriJghlDaC0lZWJlCuUWzt/4KizLwShTQN9Qh/IIz3j49Q1@TiQojGA4XjgTKooiCVIMXoov7@QGf5q2v@BwA "Python 2 – Try It Online"), should work, I think.

Comment: @icrieverytim `[2::2]` slices to `3579`, while `[2:8:2]` gives `357`

Comment: Python 3, [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHJqlo9IiJCXUfd399fvVatWitJr7ggJ7NEQ1MnKdrKyiQWSBlCaSMobWVlCuUax9b@LyjKzCvRUEjTUI/wj4jJ84@IBxLxEeqaCppcSHLx/jF5Ef7xIAJDDqQvHkLEY5PzBxEREf4guf8A).

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>118</s> <s>116</s> 115 bytes

Thanks to [@user2390246](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66252) for two extra bytes.

```
function(M,b=table,u=unlist(c(apply(M,1,b),apply(M,2,b),b(diag(M)),b(M[2*1:3+1]))))`if`(any(u>2),names(u[u>2]),"T")
```

Slightly ungolfed:

```r
function(M){
    u=unlist(c(apply(M,1,table), #Contingency table of the rows
             apply(M,2,table), #of the columns
             table(diag(M)), #of the diagonal
             table(M[2*1:3+1]))) #of the opposite diagonal
    `if`(any(u>2),names(u[u>2]),"T") #Give name of element that occurs more than twice in any setting
 }
```

Returns `X` if X wins, `O` if O wins and `T` in case of a tie.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BCoMwEETvfkZOu20u6q2Q/oHNpQdBRBNrSkCjqIH69Wm01IrQhYGZWd7u4BRzyppq0p2BhEo2CdnU1DJrGj1OUIHo@2b2q5BKpN8QLUHCQ4snJLjYJItO4SU@hzn6KbUqQZgZ7DVCakRbj2AzH3Kk5E7QpawV06Bf/gFJCd1UePGdirX3J6quYTEGClIM@AHmB3jvixX@oByD2x@U73y6dT/0hu4N)

Comment: `M[c(3,5,7)]` is shorter for the opposite diagonal

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>26</s></sup> 21 bytes

```apl
⌈/1 1(∨⌿⍉∘⌽,⍉,⍉⍤⊢,⊢)⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FPh76hgqHGo44Vj3r2P@rtfNQx41HPXh0gC4Qf9S551LVIB4g1gfh/2qO2CY96@x51NT/qXfOod8uh9caP2iY@6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/pykYAyFQUsEISEOwIZA0BNIA)

Algorithm taken from the J answer, and [verify a magic square.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40084/80214)

-5 bytes from Adám.

Takes input as a 3x3 integer matrix where:

1 → blank,
2 → X,
3 → O.

returns the appropriate integer for X and O, 1 if it's a tie.

### Explanation

```apl
{⌈/∨⌿(1 1∘⍉∘⌽,1 1∘⍉,⍉,⊢)⍵} ⍵ → input
     (                 )⍵  pass ⍵ to inner fn:
                      ⊢    return matrix containing argument,
                    ⍉,     argument transposed,
              1 1∘⍉,       it's main diagonal,
      1 1∘⍉∘⌽,             and the main diagonal of it's reverse.
   ∨⌿(                 )   take GCD of each column of the resultant matrix
 ⌈/                        take the maximum of that
```

Comment: `⌈/1 1(∨⌿⍉∘⌽,⍉,⍉⍤⊢,⊢)⊢`

Comment: @Adám that's the whole program?

Comment: Yeah, that's just a simple golf of yours.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 173 bytes

```python
lambda x:h(x,1)*2or+h(x,0)
h=lambda x,y:g(x,y)or g(zip(*x),y)or x[0][0]==x[1][1]==x[2][2]==y or x[0][2]==x[1][1]==x[2][0]==y
g=lambda x,y:any(all(e==y for e in r)for r in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BCsMgEETv@QqPu6kHtbeAX2L3YGkSBWuC5KD9eau0gUJhYN/OMMxeDrfFa130rQb7vD8sy5ODzCWOakuXjgIHp8@Ql2ltXsEtsRVefocx4@fNRlCT1tlIauqgqEnrws5c/eW9UYb1d8HGAjYEmHtzadWZ@cgSdkwdM9Y9@XjAAsZILrgkbsT3St4cIsT6Bg)

- Input as a matrix of `1 == X, 0 == O, -1 == _`
- Output as a single value: `2 == X, 1 == O, 0 == TIE`

-8 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

Comment: You can replace the first line with `lambda x:h(x,1)*2or+h(x,0)` for -8 bytes and `0 == TIE` (which is prettier imo).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer cool, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>124</s> <s>118</s> <s>117</s> 115 bytes

- Saved six bytes thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer); using a string to avoid commata.
- Saved one byte thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder); golfing `[j*3:j*3+3]` to `[j*3:][:3]`.
- Saved two bytes by using a magic number to compress the string.

```python
def T(B):
 for j in range(8):
	a,b,c=map(int,`0x197bf3c88b2586f4bef6`[j*3:][:3])
	if B[a]==B[b]==B[c]>0:return B[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7RCoIwFIav3VMc8EZjF6ZlZqwLHyBvuhDGWM62MmjKMKint7WKCOrm8HHOd37@/jYcOx2P414q2AZFmCNQnYETtBpMrQ8yyOzOq7HADTnXfdDqAe@i63S5ECppskzE8yxVMyFVuqOnSZIzmicsRF6roKA1I6Sgws2GraPcyOFitLuMFZmuoCTxCjjZdFoi1Bsbb3tQVGEoMVQYuQncAbeMbPa3xx/q64G/4Yf3zOPfwP955RsqV6B0nv8RfRaOdw)

#### Input / Output values

- `X` is represented as `1`
- `O` is represented as `2`
- `_` is represented as `None`

Comment: `[8,0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8,0,4,8,2,4,6]` -> `map(int,'8036147258048246')`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks. I was trying to golf the integer list by using `map(ord,"...")`, though a `nul` byte in the middle of a string did not work out...

Comment: [117 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY7BCoJAFEXXzlc8aJFTszC1kpFp4QckSAthGAY1LYVGGWzR15tNSRS1uRx4511ud@vPrXKH4VhWcLAjkjCdqVNpBxhTBFWroYFaQUKRlZGcFMxOlpess2vVk3ngeJuVv3XXgeMHrr@ZY8ybhUcFp55AVl1BxDPBWMRzk4XYOVSX/VUrcxlStgohZm4Iku1bVSLU6bF5XMJRSiAmkBJkEqQBOTIS@MuTD/X1ICf44T375CfIf148QWoGxMabvcWZwMMd). `[j*3:j*3+3]` is `[j*3:][:3]`. As a side note, `j*3+3` is the same as `-~j*3`, but that is 118 bytes too.

Comment: @JonathanFrech You seem to have an extra `01234567`...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Well, they actually were supposed to be there. The code, as it is, will not work.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Ok, sorry. Anyway, your Tio link did not have them.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks. Learnt a new slicing golf today.

Comment: I don't believe that the `>0` is necessary.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Without it, the player `None` could [win](https://tio.run/##HY5BCoMwFETX/lP8pZYsqrY2jWTjAeqmCyEETWzSKjRKsNCePlXhMQxvMcz8W16Ty0J4GIv3uEoYoJ08jjg49Mo9TUxXFymiSc/fao4Ht5Du@E2vF23znlKdnWlhT9rYohPjIWdSsFwmEA0WK6Ek55XQe/aSebN8vNt9aHhaYs2zElt@m5wBmP06vr4Q0BLc2Uq9AQ3BDZBJ@AM).

Comment: Aha, yes my mistake!

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>112</s> <s>108</s> <s>106</s> <s>104</s> <s>90</s> <s>102</s> 93 bytes

```java
b->b.replaceAll(".*(X|O)(\\1|...\\1...|.{4}\\1.{4}|..\\1..)\\1.*","$1").replaceAll("..+","T")
```

+12 bytes (90 → 102) due to bug-fix of only checking one diagonal instead of both..
-9 bytes (102 → 93) by using `replaceAll` instead of `matches`.

Input in the format `XOX OX_ O_X`, output `X`, `O` or `T`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jU/BagIxEL37FUPoIbF1QOhNWugHaA56CGgJ2RhLNGaX3SiIu9@@nd3m0ksr5M1M3rzMvBzN1czKysXj/tTbYJoGlsbH@wTAx@Tqg7EOVsMVYJ1qH7/A8lwUYkF8R6DTJJO8hRVEeIO@mL0XWLsq0POPEDjDKVetFHy3m7eISIlii/fXbigptZkUQ5yyF/Y0Z@L3CHwmesNEv/hZWV2KQCvz5mvp93Am79ne9hOMyMZvTXJnLC8JK2qlEHlEy5mSCqTSILViYvzMH1otQUlNeEBLc/UI/ZBWEpSS/2rJJ2g1@sjabtL13w)

```java
b->{                   // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  b.replaceAll(".*(X|O)(\\1|...\\1...|.{4}\\1.{4}|..\\1..)\\1.*",
                       //  If we found a line of X or O:
     "$1")             //   Replace it with either X or O
   .replaceAll("..+",  //  If there are now more than 2 characters left:
     "T")              //   Replace it with T
                       // End of method (implicit / single-line return-statement)
```

Explanation regex:

```java
.*(X|O)(\1|...\1...|.{4}\1.{4}|..\1..)\1.*
.*                                      .*# 0 or more trailing & leading chars
  (X|O)                               \1  # X or O next to those leading/trailing chars
       (\1                                # A single X or O in between (row found)
          |...\1...                       # 3 chars, X or O, 3 chars (column found)
                   |.{4}\1.{4}            # 4 chars, X or O, 4 chars (diagonal TL→BR found)
                              |..\1..)    # 2 chars, X or O, 2 chars (diagonal TR→BL found)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 51 bytes

```
.*(X|O)(\1|...\1...|.{4}\1.{4}|..\1..)\1.*
$1
..+
T
```

Port of [my Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144273/52210). Input in the format `XOX OX_ O_X`, output `X`, `O` or `T`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT0sjosZfUyPGsEZPTy/GEEjU6FWb1AJZQLIGIqQJJLS4VAy59PS0uUL@/4/wj1Dwj4hX8I@PAAA)

```
.*(X|O)(\1|...\1...|.{4}\1.{4}|..\1..)\1.*
.*                                      .*# 0 or more trailing & leading chars
  (X|O)                               \1  # X or O next to those leading/trailing chars
       (\1                                # A single X or O in between (row found)
          |...\1...                       # 3 chars, X or O, 3 chars (column found)
                   |.{4}\1.{4}            # 4 chars, X or O, 4 chars (diagonal TL→BR found)
                              |..\1..)    # 2 chars, X or O, 2 chars (diagonal TR→BL found)

$1                                        #  Replace match of above with either X or O

..+                                       # If there are now 2 or more characters left:
T                                         #  Replace everything with T
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 49 bytes

```
;
;;
.*(\w)(.)*\1(?<-2>.)*(?(2)(?!))\1.*
$1
..+
T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/B/Ppct1aBuXNZe1NYhW1QhJUEiI/w/m62lpxJRrauhpasUYatjb6BrZAZka9hpGmhr2ipqaMYZ6Wlwqhlx6etpcIf//Ryj4K0RwAbFCPJCMB7K5gEwFfy6QRDwXRBpKxcPJeJiQP5iMAGr3BwA) Takes input as an 11-character string of 9 `X`s, `O`s or `-`s in three groups of three separated by `;`s, although the link includes a header which translates the given test cases to this format. Works by matching a winning line directly using a balancing group to ensure that the three matching characters are equidistant. (Suitable distances are 0 (horizontal line), 4 (reverse diagonal), 5 (vertical line), or 6 (diagonal); other distances would hit a `;` or extend outside the string.)

Comment: Save 2 bytes by using `$.` instead of `(?!)`.

Comment: Did you suggest a golf on your own answer? xD

Comment: @KevinCruijssen When they're that old I don't think it's worth editing. I mean, it's called Retina 0.8.2 these days for a start...

Comment: Ah ok. It just struck me as odd that you suggested a golf on your own answer. I thought you did so by accident thinking it was someone else's answer back in September.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm not 100% sure but I think I noticed that a bunch of my answers could be golfed in a similar manner so I reviewed them all at the time and decided whether to edit or just comment.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Also I messed up and I can save 3 bytes by using `^` instead.

Comment: Haha. 1.5 year reply to my previous comment, which was a halve year late reply to your comment, which was a 3 year old comment on your answer. Pretty big latency. ;p

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 127 bytes

```
.*(X|O)\1\1.*
$1
(X|O).. \1.. \1..
$1
.(X|O). .\1. .\1.
$1
..(X|O) ..\1 ..\1
$1
(X|O).. .\1. ..\1
$1
..(X|O) .\1. \1..
$1
..+
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT0sjosZfM8YwxlBPi0vFkAvM1dNTAPIhBEhQDyKqoAcUABNgQYiogh5QAEwga4eohArCVYIE4WbqaXPF//8f4R@h4O/vrxAR4Q8A)

...I guess you could call this brute force... Thought there might be some merit to it...

Answer (score 1):

## J, 34 bytes

```
[:>./[:+./"1(2 1 0},:0 1 2}),(,|:)
```

Ungolfed:

```
[: >./ [: +./"1 (2 1 0} ,: 0 1 2}) , (, |:)
```

### Explanation

Encoding:

```
X = 2
O = 3
_ = 1
```

Our high-level strategy is first to create a matrix each of whose rows is a possible win.  Row one is diagonal /, row 2 is diagonal \, the next three rows are the rows, and the final three rows are the columns.  This part is accomplished by the phrase (using Item Amend `}`):

```
(2 1 0},:0 1 2}),(,|:)
```

Finally we take the GCD of each row:

```
+./"1
```

Thanks to our encoding, any row with a blank will have a GCD of 1, as will any row that contains any mix of Xs and Os, because 2 and 3 are coprime.  So all we need to do next is find the maximum element: `>./`

If the game is a tie, it will be 1.  If a player wins, it will be that player's number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7LCgIxDLz3K0IRu8XSbZJblhX/YxHBRxERhK3e3G@vqUoSZjIzkNxqLjAKJNCpk2xjP8km9hY7AoS0BEmKtPjQhbf46o2N4PIoDgIsArkYc5zPY4RJGHi9stEmM1/K6/4sqnZD9jsNWDSX0/UBfwf2QzwgOCAmZiLixrC1XlNk1F3ZV0X9BbGlmsa/Qlc/)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 66 bytes

```javascript
([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i])=>e&(a&i|c&g|b&h|d&f)|a&(b&c|d&g)|i&(c&f|g&h)
```

Keeping it simple.

- Input: A string, or array of numbers or strings, with `0` corresponding to a blank space, `1` an X, and `2` an O.
- Output: `0` for a tie, `1` for X victory, `2` for O victory.

Expanded, lightly commented:

```javascript
( [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i] ) => // Break apart the input into nine variables w/ destructuring
  // Run through all possible win conditions. 1&1&1 -> 1, 2&2&2 -> 2
  e & (             // All victories involving the middle square
    a & i | c & g | // Diagonal lines
    b & h | d & f   // Vertical/horizontal through the middle
  ) | 
  a & ( b & c | d & g ) | // Victories with the top-left square
  i & ( c & f | g & h )   // Victories with the bottom-right square
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ø«IÅ\ªIÅ/ª€êéн
```

Input as a 3x3 matrix of integers: `X=1`, `O=-1`, `empty=0`.
Output as: X wins: `[1]`; O wins: `[-1]`; tie: `[-1,1]`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I5Dqz0Pt8YcWgUk9Q@tetS05vCqwysv7P3/PzraUEfXUMcwVicaROkYQBgGQJFYAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8M7Dq2uPNwac2gVkNQ/tOpR05rDqw6vvLD3v87/6OhoQx1dQx3DWJ1oEKVjAGEYAEVidRRAsgZAeaAgWJkBjAGXheo1QGEYoMnqwlkgK4DGxcYCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ø           # Zip/transpose the (implicit) input-matrix, swapping rows/columns
 «          # Merge the list to the (implicit) input-matrix, so the list of rows in the
            # input now also contains the columns
  I         # Push the input-matrix again
   Å\       # Pop and push its main diagonal
     ª      # And append this triplet to the list as well
      IÅ/ª  # Do the same for the main anti-diagonal
€           # Now map over each triplet in the list:
 ê          #  Sort and uniquify this triplet
  é         # After the map, sort all inner lists by length
   н        # And pop and push the first (thus shortest) one
            # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

[Try it online with a step-by-step output.](https://tio.run/##TZC/TsMwEMZ3nuLU2VWaFQlVSCwdmGAidLiSS3LCtY3tUHVF4mH4MyMWluQFeAZeJDh2o3Y6677v@53vtMMN0zDMVsq0/hxm4qL7Wp7N7thk3qJyRjsqwTcEPDn67@S5JltTlPxOg2TnHXhdU@jY0dd9JN8tPibbFllByVhrhRJ0dcQKQFUCGkOhsAd0sCMpR8qqf73v3hPpSseIwy1Bpe0RisrzfCIfUtmUutHWR36r@Knlag@ED00YrCggLBtJca@/l8/@NBLobuSHX5WH9TZ7kKRq38Q7vCXzpYoHUqCVHHV8TutWbJ3PXBNY5HxQaUz9/iyHoShyMc9FvhbFWMQiPRahs/4H)